# Vertically center text on a page

Tags: vertical-alignment

How do I vertically center the text on a page?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The [memoir](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) document class provides, among a lot of other excellent things, the `vplace` environment.

Try:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{vplace}[0.7]
This is some text to be centered vertically.
\end{vplace}
\end{document}
```

`[0.7]` is an optional parameter specifying the ratio of space above to space below. The default value is `[1]`.

Comment: This is great!  I am using memoir, so I prefer this solution.

Comment: Fantastic! I think we ought to start a memoir fanclub...

Comment: I haven't tried your code above. But I am not sure your code will produce an exact vertically-centered object since I notice your code does not specify `\topskip0pt` right before `\begin{vplace}[1]`. For more details, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7286/how-to-make-an-exact-vertically-centered-object-in-a-page

Comment: @JoeCorneli Thanks for your suggested edit. I've left the brackets, simply to emphasise that it's an optional parameter, and reworded to clarify the rest.

Comment: Perhaps the anonymous down-voter would care to share his/her reasons here, so that I, and others, can learn and improve?

Comment: I can't' install the memoir package. @NeilG 's option works best.

Comment: @Nikos That's because it isn't a package but a documentclass type. So instead of `\documentclass{article}` you can use `documentclass{memoir}`.

Comment: This isn't *quite* a solution to the original question, since it requires the user to change their documentclass. There are many other document classes, and good reasons for users to use them. Therefore, a solution that works over a broad range of document classes is more appropriate, unless the question specifically asks to use this class, or specifically states that the document class is not constrained.

Comment: @MRule There is no perfect solution to this question.  If you're using memoir, this answer is probably the best solution.  If you're not using memoir, one of the other answers is more appropriate.

Answer (score 276):

This is what I found:

```
\begin{document}
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
text
\vspace*{\fill}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very useful for stuff that does not take the placement modifiers, like equations. thanks

Comment: With this suggestion, I get a perfect vertically center text on a page, but I get several blank pages in other areas of the document.

Comment: How do you solve the problem with extra blank pages like @Jh0an1Uzca73gu1 mentioned?

Comment: @DavesBroadley Sorry, but I have no idea, I used the other solution.

Comment: I use the following code, suggestion of other tex.stackexchange.com thread:

\clearpage
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering{This is some text to be centred vertically.}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\vfill % equivalent to \vspace{\fill}
\clearpage

Comment: Source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70714/center-horizontally-and-vertically-a-block-of-text

Comment: @Jh0an1Uzca73gu1 you can post it as another answer

Comment: It also works for landscape environment!

Answer (score 63):

This did the job for me:

```
\pagebreak
\hspace{0pt}
\vfill
Centered text.
\vfill
\hspace{0pt}
\pagebreak
```

Comment: why do you also need the `hspace{0pt}` ?

Comment: I want to know that, too.  It seems to be required, though.

Comment: I really don’t know/remember either,  but as Mars said it’s required. @CiprianTomoiagă

Comment: `\hspace{0pt}` is required because [vertical space is removed on the start of a document (e.g. pagebreak)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116253/tex-ignores-vskip-at-the-beginning-of-document).

Comment: Of all solutions proposed here, this is the one that worked for me.

Comment: This put it a little too far down on the page for my liking, but getting rid of the first `\hspace{0pt}` moved it up a bit.

Comment: it's easier to replace `\hspace{0pt}\vfill` with `\vspace*{\fill}`

Answer (score 4):

In ConTeXt MkIV you use `standardmakeup`.  For horizontal centering add the additional key `align=middle` as in the example below.

```
\starttext
\startstandardmakeup[align=middle]
  Centered text!
\stopstandardmakeup
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple way, like described [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Line_breaks_and_blank_spaces).

```
Text at the top of the page.

\vspace{5mm} %5mm vertical space

This text still at the top, 5mm below the first paragraph.

\vspace{25mm} %25mm vertical space

This text is somewhere in the middle.

\vfill

Text at the bottom of the page.
```

Comment: you should provide an example of document (regardless that op didn't) which show vertical centering  of text on page.