# How to make an exact vertically centered object in a page?

Tags: vertical-alignment

Note: the red lines have the same length.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=4cm,paperheight=4cm,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
%
\vspace*{\fill}%
\fbox{test}%
\vspace*{\fill}%
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the  difference you observed came from the `\topskip` that is automatically inserted. You can see the effect by commenting and uncommenting the `\topskip0pt` macro below.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=4cm,paperheight=8cm,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\vstretch}[1]{\vspace*{\stretch{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\topskip0pt
\vstretch{1}
\noindent\fbox{test}%
\vstretch{1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And thanks you for pointing out \topskip0pt as the source of problem.

Comment: I am trying to use this topskip0pt trick in a situation where I am including chapters, but unfortunately, doing so seems to insert a blank page afterward that I do not want. How can I avoid that happening?

Comment: @jdc Better to ask a different question with a minimal. You probably adding some space and the page overflows forcing TeX to issue a new page.

Answer (score 10):

I got the solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=4cm,paperheight=4cm,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}%
\noindent%
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}%
\centering\fbox{test}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```