# Why does \vspace*{0pt} add vertical space?

Tags: macros, spacing, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to format the title of the table of contents using the `tocloft` package. It inserts code that looks like the following.

```
\par
\vspace*{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}%
% code to typeset \contentsname
```

The `\vspace*` is adding unwanted space. Here's a minimal example demonstrating the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{0pt}%
ASDF
\end{document}
```

Compare that to `\vspace{0pt}` (or simply omitting the `\vspace` line altogether).

The difference between `\vspace` and `\vspace*` is clear. With the star, it expands to

```
\dimen@\prevdepth
\hrule \@height\z@
\nobreak
\vskip#1%
\vskip\z@skip
\prevdepth\dimen@
```

and without the star, it expands to just the two `\vskips`.

Why is there the extra space? (And bonus question: Doesn't this make `\vspace*` sort of worthless since the star only has a use when TeX is discarding items?)

**Edit:**
I was able to fix my real problem (with the table of contents) by using `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox`.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is related to `\topskip` as explained here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7286/how-to-make-an-exact-vertically-centered-object-in-a-page

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To ensure that white space is produced even at points in the document where page breaking takes place or at the top or bottom of a page one should replace `\vspace` by `\vspace*`.

At the beginning of a page `\topskip` is inserted, normally `\topskip=10pt`. Setting   `topskip=0pt` and `\offinterlineskip` will produce identical results both for `vspace` and `vscpace*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\topskip=0pt  \offinterlineskip 
\vspace*{0pt}%
ASDF

\end{document}
```

`\offinterlineskip` is macro to prevent interline glue globally. Try running both examples to see the difference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\topskip=0pt  %\offinterlineskip 
\vspace*{0pt}%
ASDF
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Yiannis, I already gave @TH the link where you explained almost the same answer.

Comment: `\offinterlineskip` doesn't seem to be needed. And `\prevdepth` wasn't contributing anything in my example since it was 0pt. `\topskip` is really the culprit. As _TeX by Topic_ points out, if you want to really start at the top of the page, you should use `\hbox{}\kern-\topskip`.

Comment: @TH I think it does (at least for my example), if you comment it out it will still have an effect. See TeXbook exercise 12.10. Why do you say in your example `\topskip` was zero?

Comment: @xport yes thanks, I saw it but just wanted to clear all these in my mind as well and I thought you went for lunch, while I am having breakfast:)

Comment: @Yiannis: I didn't. I said that `\prevdepth` is zero.

Comment: @TH Interesting stuff, how do you know `prevdepth` was zero?

Comment: @Yiannis: I used `\showthe\prevdepth`.

Comment: @TH Doesn't it shows zero because there was no last box yet?

Comment: @Yiannis: Yes. For the first box on the page, TeX doesn't look at `\baselineskip`, `\lineskiplimit`, or `\lineskip`. "Before the first box on each page some glue is inserted. This glue has the same stretch and shrink as `\topskip` but the natural size is the natural size of `\topskip` minus the height of the first box, or zero if this would be negative." – _TeX by Topic_, Section 26.2. `\topskip0pt` is the key.

Comment: @Yiannis: If you comment out `\offinterlineskip` in your example, the top of the first line (namely `\the\dimen@`) is still at the very top of the text area. Exercise 12.10 in _The TeXbook_ doesn't have anything to do about this particular issue. It's just talking about `\nointerlineskip`. I want to accept an answer for this question but I think the only part of yours that is correct and relevant is "At the beginning of the page `\topskip` is inserted, normally `\topskip=10pt`." If you remove the other stuff, I'll accept it.

Comment: @TH I had a good look at the whole issue and I will give it a good edit in the morning as it is getting a bit late here. We are both partly right here. I was wrong with `prevdepth`.  However, if you do a `tracingall` TeX inserts a `baselineskip` after a rule, hence the need for `interlineskip`. However, the major culprit is `topskip`.

Comment: @Yiannis: Please don't forget the good edit. It wouldn't be good to leave the answer as is.

Comment: @Hendrik I did a couple of changes to incorporate your suggestions. Please feel free to edit the answer further if you wish.

Comment: @Yiannis: `\offinterlineskip` is a bit extreme. I think it'd be better to use `\nointerlineskip` there which just sets `\prevdepth` to `-1000 pt` just like `\hrule` does. `\offinterlineskip` sets `\baselineskip` to `-1000 pt`, `\lineskip` to `0 pt`, and `\lineskiplimit` to `\maxdimen`.