# Adding vertical space at the start of a page

Tags: spacing, page-breaking

I'd like to, first thing before writing anything on a page, add some vertical space.

Minimal (non)working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\vspace{250px}
I want to be further down on the page :(

\vspace{250px}
Haha! Sucker :D
\end{document}
```

[image: Whhhhhhy????]

How can I get the first `\vspace` to work, just like the second one?

Comment: I wish every example came with such an instructive picture. :-)

Answer (score 275, accepted):

The space added by `\vspace` is deleted at the beginning of the page, as you have seen.  The command `\vspace*` adds the space that is *not* deleted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{250px}
I want to be further down on the page :(

\vspace{250px}
Haha! Sucker :D
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know a way to do this that math stack exchange will recognize?

Comment: @kontextify The space at the beginning of a page is deleted for a reason.  Normally space is used to separate blocks of text (like an equation and the following text); when a new block starts a page, this separation is no longer needed

Answer (score 74):

Spaces at page breaks are swallowed, as usually one doesn't want them. TeX starts counting from zero, so the first page *is* after a page break. :)

The solution is to issue `\vspace*` instead of `\vspace`.

I recommend not to use `px` which is not what one with a CSS background would expect. Use rather `cm`, `mm` or `in` or multiples of `\baselineskip`:

```
\vspace*{2cm}
\vspace*{4\baselineskip}
```

The default value of `1px` is just `1bp` (where 72bp = 1in); it's a special unit of measure that can be tailored for specific applications concerning on-screen only documents. For example, to make a document as wide as a 1200 pixel screen at 96dpi, one can pass **geometry** a paper width of 1200px by

```
\pdfpxdimen=1in % just to start the computation
\divide\pdfpxdimen by 96 % 96 px are now 1in
\geometry{paperwidth=1200px}
```

For "paper" document, this is irrelevant.

Comment: @Speldosa This is not easy: knowing that the first page is like the other as far as page breaks are concerned is not very intuitive at the beginning.

Comment: That's for sure. I've been using LaTeX for over a year now and I still feel like a beginner :) Thanks for the elaboration on px vs other units. You wouldn't happen to have any link to any kind of resource where I can learn more?

Comment: @Speldosa About `px` there's not much around, you can look at `texdoc pdftex`, where it's explained on page 32.

Answer (score 40):

In addition to the flurry of `\vspace*` suggestions, you could also issue a "nothing" command to allow subsequent `\vspace`s to typeset as expected. This "nothing" command could be an `\mbox{}` (an empty box) or `\null`, provided that you leave an empty line (or `\par`) to be in vertical mode.

More specifically, you would need

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\mbox{}% or \null; note the blank line below. Alternative, add \par on this line.

\vspace{250px}
I want to be further down on the page :(
\end{document}
```

although `\null` is a better choice - it does not require the blank line or even `\par`.

Comment: I actually tried using a `\mbox{}` command without any success. Does that compile as it should for you?

Comment: @Speldosa: I've added some more content to show exactly what I mean.

Comment: `\mbox` does `\leavevmode`, so adding a `\baselineskip` to the specified dimension; `\null` is better (and doesn't even require a blank line after it).

Comment: What the...Ah. I forgot to add the blank line when I tried it out. It compiles fine now.

Comment: @egreg: Good observation!

Comment: @Werner: Great answer! Using \null makes it work with plain TeX too, which is what I was looking for now.

Comment: Using `\vspace{xx px}` inside a `\begin{figure}` construct also worked beautifully for me when I needed to align the top edges of two graphs for aesthetic purposes in a two-column paper.

Answer (score 8):

I ***did*** try to post this as a comment, but it didn’t fit, not even in a more succint version... :-(

I chanced upon this question, and, while reading the answers and the comments, I thought that it would be worthwhile to add a reference to the following two questions:

- [Why does \vspace*{0pt} add vertical space?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7676)
- [A fix for \vspace*, does it break other things?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7682)

Note, besides, that [@egreg’s comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33370/adding-vertical-space-at-the-start-of-a-page/33373#comment65995_33375), that recommends to avoid using `\mbox{}`, and to use `\null` instead, is not entirely correct: it is true that `\null` doesn’t require to be followed by a blank line (or by a `\par`); it is true that it is much more efficient, in that it avoids starting a new paragraph and adding one level of boxing; but it is *not* true that the two solutions yield different results.  Indeed, both end up adding to the main vertical list the following things (omitting some items for simplicity):

- the `\topskip` glue;
- a zero-height `\hbox`;
- the skip specified in the argument of `\vspace`;
- the `\parskip` glue;
- the `\baselineskip` glue;
- what comes next.

(The above claim can be easily verified with `\showlists`.)