# Annoying behaviour of \vspace

Tags: spacing, page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding vertical space at the start of a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33370/adding-vertical-space-at-the-start-of-a-page)

Basically I am making a title page and I want the title to be in the center of the text

```
\documentclass[15pts]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\textwidth = 500pt
\textheight = 700pt
\voffset = -90pt
\oddsidemargin = -10pt

\begin{document}
\vspace{9000pt}

\begin{center} 
\big {Title Page} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And no matter how much I change (...pt), it stays the same.

Note that I do not want to change the formatting of my document because I got other pages to deal with too.

Comment: `\vspace` is removed at page breaks, and the first page comes, by convention, after a page break. `\vspace*` isn't removed. However `\big` doesn't change the font size (and will produce an error).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the starred version `\vspace*` which also adds space at the start of the page.