# How do I add a line automatically before a listing

Tags: spacing, listings

I am using the `listings` package and I want to automatically add a blank line before every listing. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`listings` has a parameter `aboveskip` that defines the space above a listing. Set globally by adding `\lstset{aboveskip=<length>}` to the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report} 
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{aboveskip=2\baselineskip,
frame=single}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\begin{lstlisting}
This be a listing.
\end{lstlisting}
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah excellent! That worked perfectly for me. I must have missed that in the `listings` documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to create your own environment that adds the skip:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,listings}
\lstnewenvironment{mylisting}[1][,]
  {\vspace*{\baselineskip}%
   \lstset{#1}% Add more default options here
  }{}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{mylisting}
Here is a listing
\end{mylisting}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The use of `\vspace*` will insert a skip of `\baselineskip` (an empty line) even if the listing starts at the top of the page. If you wish to not have this, using `\vspace` instead should do the trick. As reference, see [Adding vertical space at the start of a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33370/5764).