# Aligning text to bottom of page

Tags: xetex

I need to "justify" my text to the bottom of the page, like the image below. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Have you tried any of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3318933/811098) solutions?

Comment: Do you need to keep the two column layout, exactly as in the picture? It seems to me that in the image provided, it is not really bottom aligned but each paragraph is roughly aligned with the corresponding text in the other language.

Comment: @Pouya's link broke. Archive's Wayback Machine version: https://web.archive.org/web/20140702062403/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318933/latex-how-to-get-an-empty-page-with-text-at-bottom

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\null
\vfill
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem.

\columnbreak

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem.

Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien
est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien
est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. 
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to CTAN and search for 'parallel'. You will find several packages for typesetting parallel column. F.ex. 'paracol' may suit you. Combine the 'paracol'- package either with the command 'flushbottom' or use a packages that automatically flush bottom (book or report).

Answer (score 1):

For a soft column break, insert a fixed vertical gap and let TeX perform the column break automatically:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{.3\textheight plus .5\baselineskip minus .5\baselineskip}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

I've added some glue (of `.5\baselineskip` either way) to the initial vertical space. This allows for some movement if you're using different font sizes.

Note the starred use of `\vspace` at the start of a page. See [Adding vertical space at the start of a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33370/5764).