# Best way to include a line under title

Tags: titles, rules

I'm trying have a line that spans the width of the page after my name and title. Something that looks similar to this:

[image]

I am hoping that there's a document class that will allow me to do it easily, however I've been unable to find anything so far.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: @Werner Currently article, but I'm hoping there is one that would automatically add it after a \maketitle command or something.

Comment: Maybe you are just looking for `\\\null\hrulefill\null\\ ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a generic title-separating rule you can use

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{My title \endgraf\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}}
\author{My author}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

There's also a patch of `\@maketitle` possible via [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\vskip 1.5em}% <search>
  {\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}\par\vskip 1.5em}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\title{My title}
\author{My author}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

And then there's also just a straight `\underline`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{\underline{\makebox[\textwidth]{My title}}}
\author{My author}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you don't really have to use `\maketitle`. You can just create your own title that matches the original definition of `\@maketitle` in [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls):

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\fi
```

So, for example, perhaps something like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

% Your title here...
\vspace*{2em}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33370/5764
\begin{center}
  {\LARGE My title \par}
  \hrulefill\par
  \vspace{1.5em}
  {\large My author \par
  \vspace{1em}
  \today \par}
\end{center}
\par
\vspace{1.5em}

\end{document}
```

...and obviously many more options...

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the last one you suggested. Is there a way to have it so that it shows up under the Author instead? I tried to put the \underline command in the author box but that just messed up the formatting.

Comment: @Eabryt: A quick fix, similar to the last suggestion is to use `\author{\makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep]{\underline{\makebox[\textwidth]{My author}}}}`. The difference between the `\title` and the `\author` is that the latter is actually set inside a `tabular`; so there's `\tabcolsep`s involved.