# Using \line Inside of \title

Tags: titles, line

I am currently working on formatting a title page for my MSc thesis and am having a hard time getting some lines over and under my title to line up.

Here is what I have so far:

```
\linethickness{0.05cm}

\title{\line(1,0){450} \\ MSc Thesis \line(1,0){450}}

\author{\Large John Smith \\ \normalsize Supervisor: Dr. John Smith}

\maketitle
```

As you can see from the picture, the bottom line is further from the title than the top line and I cant figure out how to fix it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232390/best-way-to-include-a-line-under-title/232393#232393 could be helpful

Answer (score 3):

The `titling` package has several tools to customise the layout of title pages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{titling}
\makeatletter
\def\supervisor#1{\gdef\@supervisor{#1}}
\supervisor{John Smith, Esq.}
%
\setlength{\droptitle}{2cm}
\maketitlehooka{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\pretitle{\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.5mm }\vspace*{3ex}\par\centering\bfseries\LARGE}
\title{MSc Thesis}
\posttitle{\vspace{2ex}\par\rule{\textwidth}{0.5mm}}
\preauthor{\bigskip\begin{center}\Large}
\author{Jack Smith}
\postauthor{\medskip\par\normalsize Supervisor: \@supervisor\par\end{center}}
\predate{\bigskip\begin{center}}
\postdate{\end{center}\cleardoublepage}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Blablabla

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's better to redefine the environment. In this way you can define a new command for supervisor and don't use author for both you and the supervisor. Also you have more control over the page.

You could create commands like `\title`, `\author`, etc... with:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@supervisor}{}
\newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{\renewcommand{\@supervisor}{#1}}
\makeatother
```

You can set the supervisor with `\supervisor{Dr. John Smith}` and you can use its value with `\@supervisor` just like `\title`, `\author` and similar.

The original definition of the title page is through the `titlepage` environment.

```
\begin{titlepage}%
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \null\vfil
  \vskip 60\p@
  \begin{center}%
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 3em%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
  \end{center}\par
  \@thanks
  \vfil\null
\end{titlepage}%
```

You could modify it adding lines and supervisor. In the following the complete solution with the result.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@supervisor}{}
\newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{\renewcommand{\@supervisor}{#1}}
\makeatother

\title{MSc Thesis}
\author{John Smith}
\supervisor{Dr. John Smith}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\begin{titlepage}%
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \null\vfil
  \vskip 60\p@
  \begin{center}%
    \hrule height .5mm
    \vspace{25pt}
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vspace{25pt}
    \hrule height .5mm
    \vskip 3em%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        {\Large\@author} \\
        {\normalsize\@supervisor}
      \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
  \end{center}\par
  \@thanks
  \vfil\null
\end{titlepage}%
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Of course another valid solution is to redefine `\maketitle` command. However in my humble opinion there is no need for that if you're not going to create a class.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably better to use `\hrule` in this case,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title{
\hrule height 1mm
\vspace{25pt}
MSc Thesis
\vspace{25pt}
\hrule height .25mm
}

\author{\Large John Smith \\ \normalsize Supervisor: Dr. John Smith}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\end{document}
```

You can tune the height of each `\hrule` by passing the right argument, also the width can be adjusted.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Romain

Comment: Glad it was what you were looking for, you can accept the answer if you are happy with it :-)

Comment: Using commands like `\hrule` and `\vspace` inside the argument of `\title` is not recommendable: rather, have recourse to the `titlepage` environment, that lets you format the title page as you wish.  @CameronF.: This remarks applies to the original question too.