# Problem with newlfm package

Tags: graphics, rules, newlfm

I am downloading an sample of a cover letter and I need to modify it. Here is the code :

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Long Lined Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (1/6/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Matthew J. Miller
% http://www.matthewjmiller.net/howtos/customized-cover-letter-scripts/
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno,sigleft]{newlfm} % Extra options: 'sigleft' for a left-aligned signature, 'stdletternofrom' to remove the from address, 'letterpaper' for US letter paper - consult the newlfm class manual for more options

\usepackage{charter} % Use the Charter font for the document text

\newsavebox{\Luiuc}\sbox{\Luiuc}{\parbox[b]{1.75in}{\vspace{0.5in}

\includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{logo.png}}} % Company/institution logo at the top left of the page

\makeletterhead{Uiuc}{\Lheader{\usebox{\Luiuc}}}

\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt} % Slightly decrease the height of the signature field
\newlfmP{addrfromphone} % Print a phone number under the sender's address
\newlfmP{addrfromemail} % Print an email address under the sender's address
\PhrPhone{Phone} % Customize the "Telephone" text
\PhrEmail{Email} % Customize the "E-mail" text

\lthUiuc % Print the company/institution logo

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   YOUR NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\namefrom{John Smith} % Name

\addrfrom{
\today\\[12pt] % Date
123 Broadway \\ % Address
City, State 12345
}

\phonefrom{(000) 111-1111} % Phone number

\emailfrom{john@smith.com} % Email address

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ADDRESSEE AND GREETING/CLOSING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\greetto{Dear Mrs. Smith,} % Greeting text
\closeline{Sincerely yours,} % Closing text

\nameto{Dr, smith\xxx\\yyyyy\\
    zzzz   } % Addressee of the letter above the to address

\addrto{
yyyyyyyyyyzzzz
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LETTER CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PARAGRAPH ONE: State the reason for the letter, name the position or type of work you are applying for and identify the source from which you learned of the opening (i.e. career development center, newspaper, employment service, personal contact).

PARAGRAPH TWO: Indicate why you are interested in the position, the company, its products, services - above all, stress what you can do for the employer. If you are a recent graduate, explain how your academic background makes you a qualified candidate for the position. If you have practical work experience, point out specific achievements or unique qualifications. Try not to repeat the same information the reader will find in the resume. Refer the reader to the enclosed resume or application which summarizes your qualifications, training, and experiences. The purpose of this section is to strengthen your resume by providing details which bring your experiences to life. 

PARAGRAPH THREE: Request a personal interview and indicate your flexibility as to the time and place. Repeat your phone number in the letter and offer assistance to help in a speedy response. For example, state that you will be in the city where the company is located on a certain date and would like to set up an interview. Alternatively, state that you will call on a certain date to set up an interview. End the letter by thanking the employer for taking time to consider your credentials. 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

I need just to remove the logo and the two lines in the top and the bottom. I tried to comments but I get errors.

```
%\newsavebox{\Luiuc}\sbox{\Luiuc}{\parbox[b]{1.75in}{\vspace{0.5in}

%\includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{logo.png}}}
```

Comment: The box `\Luiuc` is used in `\makeletterhead`, commenting it out will lead to an error of course

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple adaptation that replicates your [`newlfm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm) letter inside the `article` document class:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{charter} % Use the Charter font for the document text
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indent
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip}
\pagestyle{empty}% No headers/footers

\begin{document}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33373/5764
% \vspace*{<len>}% If you want to start lower down the first page.

\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
  \today \\ \\
  123 Broadway \\
  City, State 12345 \\
  Phone: (000) 111-1111 \\
  Email: john@smith.com
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  Dr.\ Smith \\
  xxx \\
  yyyyyy \\
  zzzz \\
  yyyyyyyyyyzzzz
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Dear Mrs.\ Smith,

\bigskip  

PARAGRAPH ONE: State the reason for the letter, name the position or type of 
work you are applying for and identify the source from which you learned of 
the opening (i.e.\ career development center, newspaper, employment service, 
personal contact).

PARAGRAPH TWO: Indicate why you are interested in the position, the company, 
its products, services - above all, stress what you can do for the employer. 
If you are a recent graduate, explain how your academic background makes you 
a qualified candidate for the position. If you have practical work 
experience, point out specific achievements or unique qualifications. Try 
not to repeat the same information the reader will find in the resume. Refer 
the reader to the enclosed resume or application which summarizes your 
qualifications, training, and experiences. The purpose of this section is to 
strengthen your resume by providing details which bring your experiences to 
life. 

PARAGRAPH THREE: Request a personal interview and indicate your flexibility 
as to the time and place. Repeat your phone number in the letter and offer 
assistance to help in a speedy response. For example, state that you will be 
in the city where the company is located on a certain date and would like to 
set up an interview. Alternatively, state that you will call on a certain 
date to set up an interview. End the letter by thanking the employer for 
taking time to consider your credentials. 

\bigskip

Sincerely yours,

\vspace{50pt}

John Smith

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove also the `\makeletterhead` instruction (the documentation explains how to make your own).

For the rules, you can set their thickness with `\Headlinewd` and `\Footlinewd`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno,sigleft]{newlfm}

\usepackage{charter} % Use the Charter font for the document text

\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt} % Slightly decrease the height of the signature field
\newlfmP{addrfromphone} % Print a phone number under the sender's address
\newlfmP{addrfromemail} % Print an email address under the sender's address
\PhrPhone{Phone} % Customize the "Telephone" text
\PhrEmail{Email} % Customize the "E-mail" text

\Headlinewd{0pt}
\Footlinewd{0pt}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   YOUR NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\namefrom{John Smith} % Name

\addrfrom{
  \today\\[12pt] % Date
  123 Broadway \\ % Address
  City, State 12345
}

\phonefrom{(000) 111-1111} % Phone number

\emailfrom{john@smith.com} % Email address

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ADDRESSEE AND GREETING/CLOSING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\greetto{Dear Mrs. Smith,} % Greeting text
\closeline{Sincerely yours,} % Closing text

\nameto{% Addressee of the letter above the to address
  Dr, smith\\
  yyyyy\\
  zzzz
}

\addrto{% address
yyyyyyyyyyzzzz
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LETTER CONTENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PARAGRAPH ONE: State the reason for the letter, name the position or type of work you are applying for 
and identify the source from which you learned of the opening (i.e. career development center, 
newspaper, employment service, personal contact).

PARAGRAPH TWO: Indicate why you are interested in the position, the company, its products, services - 
above all, stress what you can do for the employer. If you are a recent graduate, explain how your 
academic background makes you a qualified candidate for the position. If you have practical work 
experience, point out specific achievements or unique qualifications. Try not to repeat the same 
information the reader will find in the resume. Refer the reader to the enclosed resume or application 
which summarizes your qualifications, training, and experiences. The purpose of this section is to 
strengthen your resume by providing details which bring your experiences to life.

PARAGRAPH THREE: Request a personal interview and indicate your flexibility as to the time and place. 
Repeat your phone number in the letter and offer assistance to help in a speedy response. For example, 
state that you will be in the city where the company is located on a certain date and would like to set 
up an interview. Alternatively, state that you will call on a certain date to set up an interview. End 
the letter by thanking the employer for taking time to consider your credentials.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

[image]