# px in pdflatex to xelatex

Tags: units

I have document with many figures as following:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, trim = 0px 200px 100px 30px,clip]{A.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, trim = 83px 210px 150px 115px,clip]{B.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption text}
\end{figure}
```

Document were compiled by pdflatex therefore px unites were used. How this can be compiled by xelatex where px unit are not supported. What is the simplest modification to preserve the same visual impression?

Comment: Using `px` is wrong to begin with, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33370/adding-vertical-space-at-the-start-of-a-page/33372?s=1|0.1107#33372

Comment: @egreg this aroused my curiosity a bit. Do you know if XeTeX's definition of `pt` is different than PdfLaTeX? (I compiled the OP's example with both and the results are tremendously different)

Comment: Of course 1pt is the same for both engines

Comment: If you don't change `\pdfpxdimen` as explained in the linked answer, the value of `1px` is the same as `1bp` (and XeTeX knows `bp` units).