# Unexpected pagebreak

Tags: templates, cv

I created my cv using this cv template:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/material-cv/rnrnhvmfxyrw
and here's my edited files:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ok8ftdktnjep6nh/AABmMCzZ3bjDmskger0Oi-YJa?dl=0

My question is, if I force pagebreak the template looks as it should:
[image: fig1]

[image: fig2]

But if I remove the page break as in fig2, latex puts an unneccessary (and unwanted) pagebreak right after contacts section. This forces me to change the \vspace right after begin{document} and sometimes change the pagebreak's position whenever I edit information. What's the cause and how can I solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The template inserts a number of `\vspace`s to creating the appropriate layout spacing. However, in most cases, it uses `\vspace*` (as opposed to `\vspace`), which inserts a `\nobreak` within the code.

You may want to remove these `\vspace*` insertions manually (as you may want to keep a CV heading with its sectional content, but would allow a break between the sections.

Alternatively, a quick-fix (which is not perfect) would be to make `\vspace*` be equivalent to `\vspace` by adding the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\vspace{\@ifstar\@vspace\@vspace}
\makeatother
```

Comment: If I add those lines to the preamble, surely sections align, but I can't push the name-surname and the picture down... They're always at the top

Comment: @bonc: Instead of `\vspace*{85pt}`, use `\par\rule{0pt}{85pt}%`. Or, you can replace all `\vspace*` in your code with `\vspace` and keep only a select number of `\vspace*`. What's the difference? See [Adding vertical space at the start of a page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33370/5764).