# Decreasing top margins

Tags: margins

Is it possible to decrease the top margin in just one single page to be? I tried to use

```
\vspace{-1.5em}
```

but it doesn’t work unlike `\hspace{}` . Can anyone help me in solving this ?.

Comment: Try `\vspace*-1.5em}`.

Comment: Can you provide some code the replicates your problem? There may be many options, but it really depends on your use-case.

Comment: some code concerning precisely what Mr. @Werner ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work @Bernard

Comment: @HusseinEid: Do you have a paragraph starting on the one page and crossing over to the following, or is the break clean? Do you have floats and only floats on this strangely-different page?

Comment: My page is beginning with a formula using `\align` package. As Known, using such a command for typesetting formulas creates a little space up and down the formula. I hope to remove the space preceding the formula so that the top margin of the page starting with the formula looks familiar. @Werner

Comment: I used `\center`command and it works. Though, using `\align` is much better for typing formulas.

Comment: the space before the formula will be automatically removed at a page break.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a blank line before your `align` as shown in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet rutrum 
velit, ac fermentum risus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse tristique tempus 
turpis vitae sollicitudin. Etiam mattis quis turpis eget feugiat. Praesent at 
turpis sed nibh sodales facilisis. In fermentum scelerisque pulvinar. Quisque 
vitae ultricies tortor. Aliquam a elit ante. Donec sagittis tincidunt eros, 
eget eleifend ligula lobortis sit amet. Mauris vestibulum justo et volutpat 
tempus. Aenean luctus turpis massa, id suscipit purus blandit non.

\begin{align}% Space between paragraph and align
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  ix^2 + jx + k &= g(x) \\
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  ix^2 + jx + k &= g(x)
\end{align}

\lipsum[5-7]

\clearpage

\lipsum[1-4]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet rutrum 
velit, ac fermentum risus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse tristique tempus 
turpis vitae sollicitudin. Etiam mattis quis turpis eget feugiat. Praesent at 
turpis sed nibh sodales facilisis. In fermentum scelerisque pulvinar. Quisque 
vitae ultricies tortor. Aliquam a elit ante. Donec sagittis tincidunt eros, 
eget eleifend ligula lobortis sit amet. Mauris vestibulum justo et volutpat 
tempus. Aenean luctus turpis massa, id suscipit purus blandit non.
\begin{align}% No space between paragraph and align
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  ix^2 + jx + k &= g(x) \\
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  ix^2 + jx + k &= g(x)
\end{align}

\lipsum[5-7]

\end{document}
```

As can be seen from the above example, if you do not leave a blank line, the preceding paragraphs final line ties to the `align`.

If you do need to use negative vertical spacing, ensure that you're in vertical mode. If you're [at the top of the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33373/5764), use the starred version `\vspace*`.