# Is there any alternative to geometry package to set margins?

Tags: margins, geometry

I'm trying to change the size of the top margin for one specific page in a large document and I do not want to use the geometry package. Moreover, 
placing `\vspace{-x}` on top does not work for me either. Is there an alternative?

Best regards.

Comment: Do you want to increase (enlarge) or decrease (reduce) the top margin? Why do you want to do this? Could you provide some context?

Comment: The `geometry` is a pretty standard solution with a good documentation and an amazing `showframe` option. Why do you not want to use it?

Comment: `\vspace*` not `\vspace` is usually required to adjust space at top of a page

Comment: Regarding the use of `\vspace` at the start of a page, see [Adding vertical space at the start of a page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33370/5764) (possible duplicate).

Comment: The flowfram package can replace the text area with almost anything.

Comment: package `changepage`?

Comment: There are the raw margin commands `\oddsidemargin` etcetera, but using the geometry package would be better.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ended up solving my problem by doing \topmargin=-25mm in the beginning of the page that I wanted to reduce and then I used the same approach at the end of the page to reset it. Do you think that this qualifies be the accepted answer?