# How to bring entire title area up?

Tags: titles, moderncv, vertical-spacing

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{black}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[margin=0.63in]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}
\nopagenumbers{}

% personal data
\name{Firstname}{Lastname}
\phone[mobile]{+1 (111) 111-1111}                   
\email{myemail@gmail.com}    
\social{https://www.linkedin.com/in/mylinkedin}
\homepage{mywebsite.com}           

\pagenumbering{gobble}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

My question is simple: How can I bring the title up closer to the top of the page so that there is less white space at the very top?

Answer (score 0):

If your resume is only one page long, you can adjust the `top` margin using [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry):

```
\usepackage[margin=0.63in,top=0.5in]{geometry}
```

`margin` sets all the margins, followed by a smaller specification just for the `top`.

---

If your resume is more than one page long and you only want to achieve this for the first page, then insert a negative `\vspace` ([starred version, since you're at the top of the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33370/5764)):

```
\vspace*{-0.5in}

\makecvtitle
```