# Space reduction (for the title)

Tags: spacing, pdftex, xetex, chinese

In the provided latex code snippet below, there is excessive vertical space between the Chinese name "张三" and the top margin. As a result, my resume now extends to the second page. I am curious about how I can reduce this space to ensure that my resume fits onto one page. Thank you!

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Random Stuff %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{-3.0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{-1pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.6in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1in}
\urlstyle{same}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-5pt}\scshape\raggedright\large\bfseries
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{0pt}]
% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Commands  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{
  \item\small{
    {#1 \vspace{-5pt}}
  }
}
\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-3pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & \textbf{\small #2} \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-8pt}
}
\newcommand{\resumeSubheadingContinue}[2]{
  \vspace{-3pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textit{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-8pt}
}
\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
  \vspace{-3pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & \textbf{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-8pt}
}
\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}\vspace{0pt}}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}
\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.0in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{0pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        % NAME
        {\huge 张三} 
        % SUBHEADING
        \\
        \vspace{0.15cm}
        {\raisebox{-0.2\height}{\faPhone}
        {}}
        \vline ~
        % EMAIL
        \href{}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}{\faEnvelope}  \underline{}}
        \vline ~
        % LINKEDIN
        \href{}
        {\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faLinkedin\ \underline{LinkedIn}}
        \vline ~
        % GITHUB
        \href{}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faGithub\ \underline{GitHub}}
    \end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Hm, where does your documkent end? This way it can't compile. Please add what's missing for this purpose. // Also, please remove packages, \newcommands etc. which are not needed to show your problem. Thank you // For some more guidance on MWEs you may want to have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 and the surrounding answers.

Comment: There is no need for `\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}` followed by `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` and then setting the headers/footers to be empty. [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) is not needed, as the `empty` option with [`fullpage`](//ctan.org/pkg/fullpage) already sets `\pagestyle{empty}` (which seems to be what you're looking for).

Comment: size commands do not take an argument. `\small{` just adds a space it doesn't limit the scope of `\small`

Answer (score 1):

If you add the [`showframe` package](//ctan.org/pkg/showframe) to your preamble, it will draw a frame around the text block that holds all of your text/CV. You'll note that the name is at the top of the frame, so for moving it up you have a couple of options:

1. Adjust the top margin of your text block to be higher on the page (reduce the top margin.

   Instead of using the [`fullpage` package](//ctan.org/pkg/fullpage) with subsequent adjustments to margins, use [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) and set `margin = 0.5in` (say), and then tweak `top` as needed (for example, `top=0.25in`). If you follow this approach, also add `\pagestyle{empty}` to your preamble to remove any headers/footers.

   `geometry` also offers the `showframe` package option that draws a frame around the text block to showcase the margins. Now it should be easy to adjust the margins to suit your needs.
2. Insert a negative `v`ertical `space` before setting your title; this should push it up/above the text block top margin.

   For this use `\vspace*{<negative length>}`, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33370/5764), since the space needs to be added (actually subtracted) at the top of the page.

Here is a minimal example showing option 1:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin = 0.25in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  % NAME
  {\huge Name}

  \medskip

  % SUBHEADING
  \faPhone ~
  \vline ~
  % EMAIL
  \faEnvelope ~
  \vline ~
  % LINKEDIN
  \faLinkedin\ \underline{LinkedIn}
  \vline ~
  % GITHUB
  \faGithub\ \underline{GitHub}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

It's still not working. I used the exact same packages/layouts for both of my Chinese and English resumes, but the top margin of the Chinese version is much higher than the English one. Even if it draws a frame that you said, it still extends to the second page by at least 1/3 of the page (two sections). 

Changing the top margin doesn't really do anything and sometimes half a page just disappears if the value is large. 

If you don't mind, I can send you both resumes with tex files (without meaning texts) by email and take a look from there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Louis: Paste each to PasteBin.com. Remember, I may not have the fonts that you have, so provide code that doesn't rely on local changes (like fonts) yet still reproduces the issue. I can't see how the exact same code would produce different layouts.