# Caption number increases by two for every inclusion

Tags: numbering, captions, counters, marginpar

I am trying to typeset my captions in margin using `marginpar` and `captionof`. Here is what I get by the MWE. Note the wrong caption numbers.
[image: Wrong caption numbering]

The first caption is included using macro `\fixedmarginpar` and the second caption using `\marginpar`. The figure number gets incremented by 2 for every caption included using `\fixedmarginpar`.

Please read [vspace-in-marginpar-adds-unwanted-vertical-space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78519/vspace-in-marginpar-adds-unwanted-vertical-space) for the `\fixedmarginpar` macro used in MWE. This macro sets the caption in a box, and offsets the vertical alignment depending on the height of the box. The caption number is incremented by two because this macro sets a box with caption for calculating the height (`\captionof` is called for the first time) and then sets it in the `marginpar` (`\captionof` is called again). Whats a good workaround?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{calc}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78519/vspace-in-marginpar-adds-unwanted-vertical-space
\newcommand{\fixedmarginpar}[2][0pt]{%
  \setbox0=\vtop{#2}\marginpar{\vspace{\dimexpr-\ht0+#1}#2}%
}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\fixedmarginpar{\captionof{figure}{A}}
\marginpar{\captionof{figure}{A}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The figure number is stepped every time  twice, because you're typesetting the caption twice. You can avoid this by typesetting it only once:

```
\newcommand{\fixedmarginpar}[2][0pt]{%
  \setbox0=\vtop{\parindent=0pt \hsize=\marginparwidth#2}%
  \marginpar{\vspace{\dimexpr-\ht0+#1}\box0 }%
}
```

In this way the box used for the measuring is not retypeset, but directly used.