# how to *precisely* center a quote vertically in latex?

Tags: vertical-alignment, article

I thought I'd wrap up the evening by quickly vertically centering some text in LaTeX. 
But, of course, that's not how LaTeX works :/.

I've taken [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942956/how-do-i-center-a-quote-vertically-and-horizontally-in-latex) simple approach.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % this kills the indentation
\Huge
\vspace*{\fill}
Arbeiten von zu Hause erlaubt es mir, Job und Familie problemlos zu vereinbaren.
Arbeiten von zu Hause erlaubt es mir, Job und Familie problemlos zu vereinbaren.
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

This does *not* yield precisely vertically centered text, and I have no idea why.

[image]

I'm probably missing something obvious.

---

**Update 1**: I tried [the fix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379797/how-to-precisely-center-a-quote-vertically-in-latex#comment940139_379797) commented by @GuM but it doesn't seem to help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % this kills the indentation
\Huge
\vspace*{-1\topskip plus 1fill}
Arbeiten von zu Hause erlaubt es mir, Job und Familie problemlos zu vereinbaren.
Arbeiten von zu Hause erlaubt es mir, Job und Familie problemlos zu vereinbaren.
\par
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try replacing `\vspace*{\fill}` with `\vspace*{-1\topskip plus 1fill}` (note the `1` before `\topskip`!).  I’d also add `\par` before the second `\vspace`.

Comment: Related to / possible duplicate of: [Why does \vspace*{0pt} add vertical space?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7676/69818).

Comment: @GuM thanks; I tried `\vspace*{-1\topskip plus 1fill}` but to no avail (see above update).

Comment: @GuM not sure this is the same issue as you mention; I tried `\topskip=0pt` but it also did not resolve the problem.

Comment: In your picture you show two red boxes: how are they positioned on the page, exactly?  I mean, where does the upper edge (resp., the lower edge) of the first (resp., the second) box lie?

Comment: sorry; upper and lower edge of the red boxes lie at the physical paper margins. I added them post-compilation with Preview.
They here merely serve to illustrate that the text is not, in fact, vertically centered.

Comment: be aware that the text area and the page area are two different things. `\voffset+\headsep+\headheight+\topmargin` make the upper margin between paper and text body; `\paperheight-(\voffset+\headsep+\headheight+\topmargin+\textheight)` make up the bottom margin. You need to include this into your calculations before you vertically align the motto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the `\vspace*{-1\topskip plus 1fill}` suggested by GuM, I placed the typeset content in a `\vbox`.  Note the the content is centered assuming the bottom of the `\vbox` is the **baseline** of the bottom line of text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % this kills the indentation
\Huge
\vspace*{-1\topskip plus 1fill}
\vbox{
Arbeiten von zu Hause erlaubt es mir, Job und Familie problemlos zu vereinbaren.
Arbeiten von zu Hause erlaubt es mir, Job und Familie problemlos zu vereinbaren.}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get the centering to account for descenders on the bottom line of text, I used a `minipage` instead of a `\vbox`, and enclosed the `minipage` inside of an `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % this kills the indentation
\Huge
\vspace*{-1\topskip plus 1fill}
\fboxrule=0pt\relax
\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\relax
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Arbeiten von zu Hause erlaubt es mir, Job und Familie problemlos zu vereinbaren.
Arbeiten von zu Hause erlaubt es mir, Job und Familie problemlos zu vereinbaren.
\end{minipage}}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

[image]