# Spacing difference when using boxes

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, boxes, dimensions

On the left (obtained from the MWE below), I do *not* use boxes for the title nor the body text and the title and the text appears to be in the correct spot.

However, when I attempt to use `\newsavebox`s  (MWE with `\def\UseBoxes{}` uncommented) I obtain the results on the right.

[image]
[image]

### Questions:

- What are this additional skip's being inserted and how do I get *both* to exhibit identical behavior?
- In my actual use case I can tweak the addition of the `\struts` to get correct behavior, but that also seems to need a conditional based on if the body text is more than one line. My understanding is that I should *only* need a `\strut` at the end of the body text, but that does not seem to work here.

### Notes:

- A vertical space defined by `\DesiredSkipAboveTitle` is added *before* the title and a `\DesiredSkipBelowTitle` is added *after* the title.
- Need to run at least twice to get the `tikz` drawing in correct position.
- The `adjustbox` package can be used to move the boxes into what I think is the correct position. This can be seen with *both* `\def\UseBoxes{}` *and* `\def\UseAdjustBox{}` uncommented.  From this we see that the `\TitleBox` needs a `raise=-1.3pt` option and the `\BodyBox` requires a `raise=-13.3pt` with the `align=t`.  I would like to know where these amounts come from.

### Code:

```
\def\UseBoxes{}% Uncomment to use boxes
%\def\UseAdjustBox{}% Uncomment to use \adjustbox (with added fudge factors)
%% --------------------
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage[paperwidth=7.0cm,showframe]{geometry}

\newcommand*{\DesiredSkipAboveTitle}{5pt}
\newcommand*{\DesiredSkipBelowTitle}{10pt}

\newcommand*{\NumberOfTitleLines}{2}
\newcommand*{\Title}{A Title that Takes Up Two Lines}
\newsavebox{\TitleBox}
\newcommand*{\SetupTitleBox}[2]{%
    \setbox#1\vbox{%
        \bfseries\centering%
        #2%
        %\strut%
        \par%
    }%
}

\newcommand*{\BodyTextLarge}{%
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Integer id nisl porta, porttitor tellus sed, sollicitudin erat. 
    Aliquam tellus urna, feugiat et tortor quis, aliquam mattis orci.% 
}%
\newcommand*{\BodyTextSmall}{%
    Small Text.% 
}%

\newcommand{\SelectedBodyText}{\BodyTextLarge}
%\newcommand{\SelectedBodyText}{\BodyTextSmall}


\newsavebox{\BodyBox}
\newcommand{\SetupBodyBox}[2]{%
    \setbox#1\vbox{%
        \noindent#2%
        %\strut%
    }%
}%

\newlength{\AdditionalSkip}
\newcommand*{\ShowTextGuideLines}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \coordinate (X) at (current page text area.north west);

    \draw [draw=red, fill=yellow, fill opacity=0.2] 
        (X) circle (1pt);%% DEBUGGING: Ensure (X) is the correct spot.

    \setlength{\AdditionalSkip}{\DesiredSkipAboveTitle}%
    \foreach \X in {1, ..., #1} {%
        \ifnum\X>\NumberOfTitleLines
            %% After title: need to adjust \AdditionalSkip for space after title
            \setlength{\AdditionalSkip}{%
                \dimexpr\DesiredSkipAboveTitle+\DesiredSkipBelowTitle\relax%
             }%
        \fi
        \draw [thin, red] ([yshift=-\X\baselineskip-\AdditionalSkip]X) -- ++ (\hsize,0);
    }%

    \tikzset{Node Style/.style={anchor=south, draw=red, inner sep=1pt}}
    \ifdefined\UseBoxes
        \node [Node Style, fill=yellow] at ([xshift=0.5\hsize]X) {using boxes};
    \else
        \node [Node Style, fill=green] at ([xshift=0.5\hsize]X) {Not using boxes};
    \fi
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%


\begin{document}
    %% ---------------------------------------------------------- Set up the title and body
    \SetupTitleBox{\TitleBox}{\Title}%
    \SetupBodyBox{\BodyBox}{\SelectedBodyText}%
    %% ---------------------------------------------------------- Title
    \hbox{}\kern-\topskip%% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7676/why-does-vspace0pt-add-vertical-space#comment12433_7681
    \vspace*{\DesiredSkipAboveTitle}%
    %%
    \ifdefined\UseBoxes
        \ifdefined\UseAdjustBox% Following tweaks seem to be close
            \noindent\adjustbox{valign=t,raise=-1.3pt}{\usebox{\TitleBox}}%
            \vspace*{\DesiredSkipBelowTitle}%
            \par\noindent\adjustbox{valign=t,raise=-13.3pt}{\usebox{\BodyBox}}%
        \else
            \noindent\usebox{\TitleBox}%
            \vspace*{\DesiredSkipBelowTitle}%
            \par\noindent\usebox{\BodyBox}%
        \fi
    \else
        \noindent{\bfseries\centering\Title\par}%
        \vspace*{\DesiredSkipBelowTitle}%
        \par\noindent\SelectedBodyText%
    \fi
    \noindent\ShowTextGuideLines{7}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: you used vbox rather than vtop (not that either of them are really latex)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Using `\vtop` instead of `\vbox` seems to resolve the issue with the `\TitleBox`, but _not_ the `\BodyBox`?

Comment: I didn't actually run the code, I'll look in a bit:-) but getting spacing around boxes right is tricky you need to control the first and last baseline but boxes only have one reference point, hence latex3 coffins, boxes with handles.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it would probably be useful to understand how TeX normally inserts vertical space between lines/boxes.
This will make it clear why this spacing is different when you wrap your paragraphs in a `\vbox`, as in your MWE.
A method to achieve identical spacing with and without boxes can be found at the bottom this answer.

### About `\baselineskip` and `\lineskip`

TeX normally tries to insert an appropriate amount of space between lines so that subsequent baselines are separated by `\baselineskip`. 
If it fails to do so without causing the distance between the boxes containing these lines to fall below `\lineskiplimit` it'll insert `\lineskip` instead.
Since `\lineskiplimit=0pt` by default, this happens precisely when the boxes would otherwise overlap.

Because `\baselineskip=12pt`, and `\lineskiplimit=0pt` by default for a 10pt document, this means that if the distance between consecutive baselines is `12pt` if the sum of the depth of the top line and the height of the bottom line is less than `12pt`. Otherwise, the (boxes containing these) lines will be separated by `\lineskip` (which is `1pt` by default).

Here's an illustration:

```
\parskip=0pt \parindent=0pt
An ordinary line of text
\par
Another ordinary line of text

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\rule[-5pt]{10pt}{15pt}This line has a depth of \texttt{5pt}
\par
\rule[-5pt]{10pt}{15pt}This line has a height of \texttt{10pt}
```

[image: iillutration]

Note that if you manually add additional skips, these are just added to whatever amount of space would otherwise be inserted:

```
\parskip=0pt \parindent=0pt
An ordinary line of text
\par\vspace{2mm}
Another ordinary line of text

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\rule[-5pt]{10pt}{15pt}This line has a depth of \texttt{5pt}
\par\vspace{2mm}
\rule[-5pt]{10pt}{15pt}This line has a height of \texttt{10pt}
```

[image: with vspace]

(Remark: normally, these lines would be separated by an additional `\parskip`, but I've set this length to zero.)

### The same thing, but with vertical boxes

It is no different for your `\vbox`es. A `\vbox` containing multiple lines has just a single baseline, which coincides with the baseline of the bottom line of its contents (top line for a `\vtop`).
If TeX can't separate these baselines by exactly `\baselineskip` without the boxes overlapping, it will completely ignore `\baselineskip`, put a vertical space of `\lineskip` between these boxes and call it a day.

This is the result: (green lines indicate the baselines)

```
\parskip=0pt \parindent=0pt
\vbox{The first vbox containing\\two lines}
\par
\vbox{The first vbox containing\\two lines}
```

[image: vboxes]

So the distance between the baseline of the second line of the first box and the baseline of the first line of the second box is equal to the depth of the former line plus the height of the latter line plus `\lineskip`.
In this case I think that's `0pt + 6.94444pt + 1pt = 7.94444pt` (the second number is how tall the letters `h`, `d` and `b` are).
Adding a `\strut` or some character with descenders (gjpqy) to the first `\vbox` would increase this distance by increasing the  depth of the last line of this box.

The same thing happens between consecutive `\vtop`s:

```
\parskip=0pt \parindent=0pt
\vtop{The first vtop containing\\two lines}
\par
\vtop{The first vtop containing\\two lines}
```

[image: vtops]

The only situation that likely matches your expected/desired outcome is the following:

```
\parskip=0pt \parindent=0pt
\vbox{A vbox containing\\two lines}
\par
\vtop{A vtop containing\\two lines}
```

[image: vbox and vtop## Heading ##]

This happens because the baselines are close enough together that they can be separated by exactly `\baselineskip` without the boxes overlapping. 
The space above this `\vbox` and below this `\vtop` is again going to be "wrong", however.

(Remark: `\vbox`es inserted in vertical mode are not preceded by a `\parskip`. If you do want this skip you should either insert it manually (using `\vspace{\parskip}`) or use `\noindent` to switch to horizontal mode before inserting the box.)

### The top of the page

Something similar happens at the top of the page. 
TeX tries to insert a (positive) skip that wil separate the baseline of the first box on a page from the top of the text area by `\topskip`. If it can't, it'll just place the box directly at the top.
The default value of `\topskip` is equal to the font size (so `10pt` for a 10pt document).

This is why it matters whether you put a `\vtop` or a `\vbox` at the top of your page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
  \parskip=0pt \parindent=0pt
  \vtop{A vtop containing\\two lines}
  \clearpage
  \vbox{A vbox containing\\two lines}
\end{document}
```

[image: top vtop] [image: top vbox]

In your MWE `\topskip` isn't really relevant because you've inserted `\hbox{}\kern-\topskip`. The `\hbox` creates an empty box that will be separated from the top of the text area by the full `\topskip`, and the subsequent `\kern` undoes this skip.
It is thus as if there is an invisible paragraph at the top of your document that ends where the text area begins, so TeX tries to separate the first box (after this) from the top of the text area by `\baselineskip` and insert `\lineskip` if it can't, exactly as described above.

---

---

## A solution

To get the correct spacing above a vertical box you should use `\vtop` instead of `\vbox` for the reasons outlined above.
To get the right amount of spacing below a `\vtop` you can set its depth equal to the depth of the last line and then insert a vertical skip equal to the distance between the first and the last baseline.

The command `\insertvbox`, which I define below, is intended to replace `\usebox` in your MWE (except it should not be preceded by `\noindent`). It wraps the contents of a `\vbox` (or `\vtop` or `\vcenter`, it makes no difference) you supply in both a `\vtop` and a `\vbox`, gives the `\vtop` the depth of the `\vbox`, prints this `\vtop` and inserts a vertical space to compensate for the decrease in depth.

Note: Because I'm using `\unvcopy`, code inside the box is only executed once. The double boxing problem pointed out by jfbu in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463039/spacing-difference-when-using-boxes/463739#comment1167780_463739) therefore does not occur.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\insertvbox[1]{%    %% <- #1 can be a vbox, vtop or vcenter
\begingroup                     %% <- limits scope of assignments
  \setbox0=\vtop{\unvcopy#1}%   %% <- wrap in a vtop
  \setbox2=\vbox{\unvcopy#1}%   %% <- wrap in a vbox
  \@tempdima=\dimexpr\dp0-\dp2\relax %% <- calculate missing depth
  \dp0=\dp2                     %% <- use depth of box2
  \par\box0                     %% <- use the vtop
  \vspace*{\@tempdima}%         %% <- insert missing depth as space
\endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

This command should *not* be preceded by `\noindent` (which switches to horizontal mode) because `\insertvbox` was intended to insert this box in vertical mode. (The `\par` in its definition actually switches back to vertical mode.)
If it is for some reason important that the box be inserted in horizontal mode (perhaps because you want a non-zero `\parskip` to be inserted), then you can replace `\par\box0` by `\par\noindent\box0` in the definition.
*(I'm afraid I don't know why the [`lineno`](https://ctan.org/pkg/lineno) package does not like the version with `\noindent` though.)*

### Example

The following example produces two identical pages: the first was constructed with vertical boxes, and the second without.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}     %% <- show boundary of text area
\usepackage{tikz}          %% <- To draw the red brackets
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} %% <- to place them correctly

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\insertvbox[1]{%
\begingroup
  \setbox0=\vtop{\unvcopy#1}%   %% <- box1 is a vtop
  \setbox2=\vbox{\unvcopy#1}%   %% <- box2 is a vbox
  \@tempdima=\dimexpr\dp0-\dp2\relax %% <- calculate missing depth
  \dp0=\dp2                     %% <- use depth of box2
  \par\box0                     %% <- use the vtop
  \vspace*{\@tempdima}%         %% <- insert missing depth as space
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\parskip=0pt   %% <- default value is "0pt plus 1pt"

\newcommand\redbracket{% %% <- for the little red brackets in the left margin
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,]
      \draw[red] (current page text area.north west) -- +(-2pt,0)
                   -- node[left]{\texttt{\detokenize{\topskip}}} +(-2pt,-\topskip) -- +(0,-\topskip);
      \foreach \X in {0, ..., 7} {
        \draw[red] ([yshift=-\topskip-\X\baselineskip]current page text area.north west) -- +(-2pt,0)
                   -- node[left]{\texttt{\detokenize{\baselineskip}}} +(-2pt,-\baselineskip) -- +(0,-\baselineskip);
      }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\TitleBox}
\newsavebox{\BodyBox}
\setbox\TitleBox=\vtop{\noindent\textbf{A title that takes\\up more than\\two lines}}
\setbox\BodyBox=\vtop{\noindent Lorem\\ipsum}

\insertvbox\TitleBox

\insertvbox\BodyBox

\insertvbox\BodyBox

\insertvbox\BodyBox

\redbracket


\clearpage

\noindent\textbf{A title that takes\\up more than\\two lines}

\noindent Lorem\\ipsum \par\noindent Lorem\\ipsum \par\noindent Lorem\\ipsum

\redbracket

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that I've set `\parskip=0pt` because the default value of `\parskip` is actually `0pt plus 1pt`.
This means that the amount of space between paragraphs could be stretched to up to `1pt` to improve the page layout.

### In your MWE

The spacing in your MWE will be correct if you replace `\noindent\usebox` by `\insertvbox` (and add the above definition to your preamble, of course):

```
\def\UseBoxes{}% Uncomment to use boxes
%% --------------------
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\usepackage[paperwidth=7.0cm,showframe]{geometry}

\newcommand*{\DesiredSkipAboveTitle}{5pt}
\newcommand*{\DesiredSkipBelowTitle}{10pt}

\newcommand*{\NumberOfTitleLines}{2}
\newcommand*{\Title}{A Title that Takes Up Two Lines}
\newsavebox{\TitleBox}
\newcommand*{\SetupTitleBox}[2]{%
    \setbox#1\vtop{%
        \bfseries\centering%
        #2%
        %\strut%
        \par%
    }%
}

\newcommand*{\BodyTextLarge}{%
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Integer id nisl porta, porttitor tellus sed, sollicitudin erat. 
    Aliquam tellus urna, feugiat et tortor quis, aliquam mattis orci.% 
}%
\newcommand*{\BodyTextSmall}{%
    Small Text.% 
}%

\newcommand{\SelectedBodyText}{\BodyTextLarge}
%\newcommand{\SelectedBodyText}{\BodyTextSmall}


\newsavebox{\BodyBox}
\newcommand{\SetupBodyBox}[2]{%
    \setbox#1\vtop{%
        \noindent#2%
    }%
}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\insertvbox[1]{%
\begingroup
  \setbox0=\vtop{\unvcopy#1}%   %% <- wrap in a vtop
  \setbox2=\vbox{\unvcopy#1}%   %% <- wrap in a vbox
  \@tempdima=\dimexpr\dp0-\dp2\relax %% <- calculate missing depth
  \dp0=\dp2                     %% <- use depth of box2
  \par\box0                     %% <- use the vtop
  \vspace*{\@tempdima}%         %% <- insert missing depth as space
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\newlength{\AdditionalSkip}
\newcommand*{\ShowTextGuideLines}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \coordinate (X) at (current page text area.north west);

    \draw [draw=red, fill=yellow, fill opacity=0.2] 
        (X) circle (1pt);%% DEBUGGING: Ensure (X) is the correct spot.

    \setlength{\AdditionalSkip}{\DesiredSkipAboveTitle}%
    \foreach \X in {1, ..., #1} {%
        \ifnum\X>\NumberOfTitleLines
            %% After title: need to adjust \AdditionalSkip for space after title
            \setlength{\AdditionalSkip}{%
                \dimexpr\DesiredSkipAboveTitle+\DesiredSkipBelowTitle\relax%
             }%
        \fi
        \draw [thin, red] ([yshift=-\X\baselineskip-\AdditionalSkip]X) -- ++ (\hsize,0);
    }%

    \tikzset{Node Style/.style={anchor=south, draw=red, inner sep=1pt}}
    \ifdefined\UseBoxes
        \node [Node Style, fill=yellow] at ([xshift=0.5\hsize]X) {using boxes};
    \else
        \node [Node Style, fill=green] at ([xshift=0.5\hsize]X) {Not using boxes};
    \fi
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%


\begin{document}
    %% ---------------------------------------------------------- Set up the title and body
    \SetupTitleBox{\TitleBox}{\Title}%
    \SetupBodyBox{\BodyBox}{\SelectedBodyText}%
    %% ---------------------------------------------------------- Title
    \hbox{}\kern-\topskip%% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7676/why-does-vspace0pt-add-vertical-space#comment12433_7681
    \vspace*{\DesiredSkipAboveTitle}%
    %%
    \ifdefined\UseBoxes
        \insertvbox{\TitleBox}%
        \vspace*{\DesiredSkipBelowTitle}%
        \insertvbox{\BodyBox}%
    \else
        \noindent{\bfseries\centering\Title\par}%
        \vspace*{\DesiredSkipBelowTitle}%
        \par\noindent\SelectedBodyText%
    \fi
    \noindent\ShowTextGuideLines{7}%
\end{document}
```

[image: output for MWE]

Note that if you want the distance between consecutive lines to be exactly `\baselineskip` even if this would cause these lines to overlap, you can set `\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen` (either inside your `\vbox`es or globally).

---

## Old solution

The macro `\copyboxwithappropriatespace`, which I define below (and which could use a better name), does roughly the same thing as `\insertvbox`. It however makes some assumptions to calculate the right depth to use and the right space to insert. It assumes that (1) it is provided a `\vtop`, (2) that the distance between the first and the last baseline inside the box is an integer multiple of `\baselinekip` and (3) that the depth of the last line is less than `\baselineskip`.
This means that the amount of space to be inserted is equal to greatest integer multiple of `\baselineskip` that is less than the depth of your box, and that that the depth of the box should be equal to the remainder (as suggested by [jfbu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4686/jfbu) in the [comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463039/spacing-difference-when-using-boxes/463739?noredirect=1#comment1167701_463739)).

```
\makeatletter                %% <-- make @ usable in command sequences
%% Inserts a box of depth 0 and insert an appropriate vspace:
\newcommand*\copyboxwithappropriatespace[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \@tempdima=\dp#1\relax   %% <-- store the depth in \@tempdima
    \count@=\@tempdima\relax %% <-- convert to a number
    \divide\count@ by \baselineskip\relax %% <-- divide by \baselineskip
    \dp#1=\dimexpr\@tempdima-\count@\baselineskip\relax %% <-- set the depth to to the remainder
    \par\copy#1%                 %% <-- insert the box
    \dp#1=\@tempdima\relax   %% <-- reset its depth
    \vspace*{\count@\baselineskip}%
  \endgroup                  %% ^-- insert \count@ \baselineskips
}
\makeatother                 %% <-- revert @
```

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you for your generosity. The second bounty wasn't necessary.

Comment: +1 but I believe there is an issue in `\copyboxwithappropriatespace`: it should not "insert multiple of \baselineskip closest to `\@tempdima`" but "insert largest multiple of \baselineskip less than `\@tempdima`". And not set the `\dp` of the inserted box to zero, but to the remainder of `\@tempdima` (i.e. the actual depth of the `\vtop` box) after removing "largest multiple of \baselineskip". To obtain that largest integer you can do `\count@\@tempdima` then `\divide\count@ by \baselineskip`. Then `\count@` has this largest integer and it times `\baselineskip` is to be removed.

Comment: @jfbu: You're right. The definition of `\copyboxwithappropriatespace` isn't perfect and was really only intended for this specific use case. If your boxes contain just normal lines of text, then it doesn't really matter whether you round down or to the nearest integer and this missed depth isn't very relevant, but in general it would be better to do precisely what you say. (It is annoying that `\dimexpr` doesn't just round down btw…)

Comment: I only just now thought of a better way to accomplish the same thing: you can create both a `\vbox` and a `\vtop` and then insert a `\vtop` with the depth of the `\vbox` and a `\vspace*` equal to the difference between their depths! This would also work if the distance between the baselines inside the box varies, (My answer is getting a little long though…)

Comment: @Circumscribe it may cause problems to have two boxing operations, typically with LaTeX counters which will get stepped twice.

Comment: @jfbu Oh yeah, I didn't think of that. I could borrow `\savecounters@`/`\restorecounters@` from `amsmath`, but it'd still not be perfect (although the AMS math environments have the same problem and everyone is happy with those).

Comment: @jfbu: I implemented your suggestion [just thought I'd let you know]

Comment: @Circumscribe looks great to me (I tried to maintain objectivity even though it came from my suggestion) :)

Comment: @Circumscribe: There seems to be a weird interaction with `\usepackage[mathlines,pagewise]{lineno}`. Adding `\linenumbers` immediately _after_ `\vspace*{\DesiredSkipAboveTitle}` produces a separate page for each box. Not that the line numbers are that useful in this case as only two get printed, but still a weird interaction. Should I just post a separate question?  Problem only occurs in the revised version of `\copyboxwithappropriatespace`. The earlier version does not have this issue.

Comment: @PeterGrill: That is weird, I'm not sure what is causing it (`lineno` is complicated). I expected `\copyboxwithappropriatespace` to be used in vertical mode, but because of the `\noindent`s in your MWE it was actually used in horizontal mode there. Removing the `\noindent`s in front of `\copyboxwithappropriatespace`, which are unnecessary (but do cause TeX to switch to horizontal mode) would solve it. I've also added a `\par` to the definition of `\copyboxwithappropriatespace` because it is not supposed to be used inside a paragraph.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I've improved the solution so that it now also works for boxes whose first and last baseline are not separated by an integer multiple of `\baselineskip`.

Comment: +1 but my remarks were too long for comment, see https://gist.github.com/jfbu/d88ad9ac67eb2bf56d36f009b9b954c8 for an `\unvtop` macro. I have not given the slightest thought to potential problems with penalties, glues, whatsits, ....

Comment: @jfbu: Nice, you're re-implementing the rules for interline glue! :D

Comment: I have not implemented *if `\prevdepth` is -1000pt or less, no glue is added*...

Comment: can you rewrite this code in L3?

Comment: I'm afraid not, @user1850133. These are the kinds of things you typically don't want to worry about when writing an actual document, so LaTeX2e does not provide interfaces for this kind of low-level box manipulation. I'm not familiar enough with expl3 to know whether LaTeX3 does.