# Environment honouring newlines and add stuff before empty lines

Tags: verse, poetry

I need an environment in which newlines are treated as newlines and that adds something at the end of lines followed by an empty line. `Alltt` is changing too many things, and even the font therefore i do not use it.

I provide my mwe, and an illustration done in lowriter. As I have no idea how to do it, i have not done anything for the new environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\fancyhead[C]{lipsum text (dummy text)}

\begin{document}
lipsum text \\ (dummy text)
\begin{myenv}
Laborum molestias nam
possimus omnis. Libero sit
maiores quas asperiores nobis
est nulla. Culpa sequi iste deserunt. ||

Adipisci fuga et quis dicta est et
odit. Illo aut nulla qui incidunt
necessitatibus nulla qui. Sunt
cumque voluptatem quasi quam  ||

\textbf{the peacock says ...}
commodi culpa quaerat sunt.
Debitis accusantium et porro et
libero nulla ut est. Asperiores sed
exercitationem aut. Ex sapiente  ||

\textbf{the elephant says ...}
Debitis nobis fugiat doloremque
voluptates enim ratione. Unde ||

magni beatae magni. Unde
voluptatum qui odio corporis quia.  ||

\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

\z as defined here is the stuff I need to add at the end of each line followed by an empty line:

```
\newcounter{versenum}\setcounter{versenum}{1}
\newcommand{\z}{\arabic{versenum}\addtocounter{versenum}{1}}
```

[image]

Comment: What happened to verse 6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done this by making a custom `\obeylines` macro which peeks ahead looking for blank lines and handles the special case when the `userverse` environment finishes.

#### Features

- Uses LaTeX `\list` environment to control vertical spacing above and below and indent within other list environments.
- Places each verse in a `\vtox` box to prevent page breaks within verses.
- Uses `\devanagaridigits` to print verse numbers

```
% TeX Program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hindi}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\hindifont[Script=Devanagari]{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Configuration
\dim_new:N \l__user_verse_left_margin_dim
\dim_set:Nn \l__user_verse_left_margin_dim { 3em }
\dim_new:N \l__user_verse_indent_dim
\dim_set:Nn \l__user_verse_indent_dim { 2em }
\skip_new:N \l__user_verse_skip
\skip_set:Nn \l__user_verse_skip { \medskipamount }
% Box to hold each verse to so page breaks are suppressed
\box_new:N \l__user_verse_box
% Counter to hold the verse number
\int_new:N \g__user_verse_number_int
% Increment verse number and output in required format
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__user_number_verse:
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g__user_verse_number_int
    \quad $\|$ ~
    \texthindi
      {
        \devanagaridigits { \int_use:N \g__user_verse_number_int }
      }
  }
% Set up custom \obeylines macro which calls \_user_do_obeylines:
\group_begin:
  \char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
  \cs_gset_protected_nopar:Nn \__user_obeylines: %
    {%
      \char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M%
      \cs_set_eq:NN ^^M \__user_do_obeylines:%
    }%
\group_end:
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__user_vbox_set_top:Nw #1
  {
    \tex_setbox:D #1 \tex_vtop:D
      \c_group_begin_token
        \color_group_begin:
  }
% Use box maintaining spacing
% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463739/87678
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__user_box_use_drop:N
  {
    \vbox_set_top:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \vbox_unpack:N #1 }
    \vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpb_box { \vbox_unpack_drop:N #1 }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \box_dp:N \l_tmpa_box - \box_dp:N \l_tmpb_box }
    \box_set_dp:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \box_dp:N \l_tmpb_box }
    \box_use_drop:N \l_tmpa_box
    \vspace* \l_tmpa_dim
  }
% Look ahead at the end of each line
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__user_do_obeylines:
  {
    \peek_meaning:NTF \__user_do_obeylines:
      {
%       add verse number and extra space if blank line found
        \__user_number_verse:
        \vbox_set_end:
        \mode_leave_vertical:
        \__user_box_use_drop:N \l__user_verse_box
        \obeyedline
        \penalty \c_zero_int
        \vspace \l__user_verse_skip
        \__user_vbox_set_top:Nw \l__user_verse_box
        \dim_set_eq:NN \hsize \linewidth
      }
      {
%       no extra space if at end of verse environment, otherwise end paragraph
        \peek_meaning:NTF \end
          { \__user_number_verse: }
          { \obeyedline }
      }
  }
% Format verses
\NewDocumentEnvironment { userverse } { }
  {
    \int_gzero:N \g__user_verse_number_int
%   User a list environment to easily set indent and handle vertical spacing
    \list { }
      {
        \skip_zero:N \parsep
        \dim_set:Nn \leftmargin
          { \l__user_verse_left_margin_dim + \l__user_verse_indent_dim }
      }
    \item
    \relax
    \__user_obeylines:
    \__user_vbox_set_top:Nw \l__user_verse_box
    \dim_set_eq:NN \hsize \linewidth
  }
  {
    \vbox_set_end:
    \box_set_wd:Nn \l__user_verse_box \linewidth
    \mode_leave_vertical:
    \__user_box_use_drop:N \l__user_verse_box
    \endlist
  }
% Outdent and format verse intros 
\NewDocumentCommand \verseintro { m }
  {
    \hspace { -\l__user_verse_indent_dim }
    \textbf {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

\begin{userverse}
  Laborum molestias nam
  possimus omnis. Libero sit
  maiores quas asperiores nobis
  est nulla. Culpa sequi iste deserunt.

  Adipisci fuga et quis dicta est et
  odit. Illo aut nulla qui incidunt
  necessitatibus nulla qui. Sunt
  cumque voluptatem quasi quam

  \verseintro{the peacock says\ldots}
  commodi culpa quaerat sunt.
  Debitis accusantium et porro et
  libero nulla ut est. Asperiores sed
  exercitationem aut. Ex sapiente 

  \verseintro{the elephant says\ldots}
  Debitis nobis fugiat doloremque
  voluptates enim ratione. Unde

  magni beatae magni. Unde
  voluptatum qui odio corporis quia.
\end{userverse}

\lipsum[11]

\selectlanguage{hindi}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{userverse}
    अअअअअअ
    अअअअअअ

    अअअअअअ
    अअअअअअ

    अअअअअअ
    अअअअअअ

    अअअअअअ
    अअअअअअ
  \end{userverse}
\end{multicols}

\selectlanguage{english}

\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I will take some time to look at it. Looking at your result, it's perfect. it. What i wanted was to make latex print the text it finds, the way `alltt` does but only for carriage returns. So far latex produces a new line only when it finds an empty line. I want an environment in which this behaviour does not occur. \obeylines seems to honour carriage returns but it does not reproduce the empty lines it finds. So in the output the spacing between the verses do not appear. Also there is my need to put a verse number as I described (though you did it).

Comment: can you add comments to explain the code. Actually in my original document I use a foreign language which involves the use of `polyglossia`. Numbers are non-arabic and therefore, i was using `\devanagarinumeral` instead of `arabic` in my post. Here with expl3 i'm stuck.

Comment: @user1850133, I added comments and wrapped in a `list` environment for smarter vertical spacing and indent handling. `\__user_number_verse:` is what formats the verse numbering. You can put whatever you want in it and call it whatever you want. You could move it outside the `expl3` block.

Comment: could you add a feature to avoid getting a verse broken on two pages?

Comment: @user1850133 I boxed up each verse in a `\vbox` to avoid page breaks. You have to keep track of the `\prevdepth` for spacing to be correct when stacking the verses on top of each other.

Comment: you did quite a lot of changes. I've not been able to add the macro to print verse number in a foreign script. The macro is this one: `\newcommand{\devanagarinumeral}[1]{%
  \devanagaridigits{\number\csname c@#1\endcsname}}`

Comment: @user1850133, I showed using `\devanaragridigits` to print the verse numbers. The main language is still English, so I wrapped it in `\foreignlanguage{hindi}{…}` but presumably your whole poem uses Devanagari script, so this won't be necessary.

Comment: well, now i have to learn expl3 since obviously i might need in the future to add new features.

Comment: @user1850133 `expl3` is a lot easier to learn than TeX. I can do things in `expl3` that I would have no hope of achieving without it. Pretty much everything you need is found in `texdoc xparse`, `texdoc expl3` and `texdoc interface3`.

Comment: could you try putting the verses in a `multicol` environment, 2 columns, with first verse in devanagari (put अअअअअअ both lines) and also the one verse which will appear at the top of the second column. I see misalignment by 1~2 mm. I tried with the basic `verse` environment and without any such environment, i.e. neither `verse` nor `userverse`, in both cases alignment if fine.

Comment: @user1850133, it might be easier to ask a new question referencing this one which demonstrates the issue. I'm guessing a bit as to your exact set up.

Comment: @user1850133 Actually, I can reproduce this. It's probably something to do with the `\prevdepth` hacks

Comment: @user1850133, I swapped the `\vbox` construction for `\vtop` and used a different method for preserving the space between boxes. It still may have problems. It's getting a bit beyond my pay grade, sorry.

Comment: your solution works perfectly for me.

Comment: I'm trying to move your code into a `.sty` file, but I would like to be able to set `\devanagaridigits` for the verse numbers from my .tex file. Can you show a solution?

Comment: @user1850133, it's better to ask a new question. From this comment I'm not really sure exactly what you want.

Comment: I'm back on this. Could you add comments that would help a novice in expl3 syntax?

Comment: @user1850133, Your best bet is to look through `texdoc expl3` which explains the variable naming scheme. Then search for the functions used in `texdoc interface3`, which gives you their syntax.

Comment: it's not expl3 my problem now. It seems you used some pure tex language. the '\relax' is to close the list environment opened by \list? the '\peak_meaning:NTF \__user_do_obeylines:' used inside '\cs_new_protected:Nn \__user_do_obeylines:' definition...

Comment: @user1850133, `\relax` does nothing and can be used when the syntax expects something (in this case after `\item`). `\list` is a LaTeX macro documented in `texdoc source2e`. `\peek_meaning:NTF` is an expl3 function documented in `texdoc interface3`. Here it looks ahead for an end of line (which has been redefined to be `\__user_do_obey_lines:`). But comments are not supposed to be for extended discussion on this site. You can ask new questions about specific things like: "What does this function do?" (Although search first in case they have already been asked.)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with regex replacement.

I inject `\obeylines` in the `myenv` environment prior to the reading of the argument, so each endline is transformed into an active `^^M`.

Then initial `^^M` tokens are removed; similarly, trailing `^^M` are replaced by `\addstanzanumber`. Next, sequences of two or more `^^M` are replaced by `\addstanzanumber\par`. The remaining `^^M` are replaced by `\\` and the resulting token list is fed to `verse`.

Initial or trailing blank lines in `myenv` are therefore ignored.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% a trick to set a token list to the active endline character
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:n { 13 }
\tl_const:Nn \c_myenv_blank_line_tl { ^^M }
\group_end:

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NV }
\tl_new:N \l_myenv_body_tl

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{+b}
 {
  \setcounter{stanzanumber}{0}
  \myenv_make:n { #1 }
  \begin{verse} \tl_use:N \l_myenv_body_tl \end{verse}  
 }
 {}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \myenv_make:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_myenv_body_tl { #1 }
  % remove any number of ^^M at the beginning
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A \u{c_myenv_blank_line_tl}* } { } \l_myenv_body_tl
  % replace any number of ^^M at the end with \addstanzanumber
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \u{c_myenv_blank_line_tl}* \Z } { \c{addstanzanumber} } \l_myenv_body_tl
  % replace any number greater than two of ^^M with \addstanzanumber
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \u{c_myenv_blank_line_tl}{2,} }% pairs ^^M^^M
   { \c{addstanzanumber}\c{par} } % replace with \addstanzanumber\par
   \l_myenv_body_tl
  % replace any remaining ^^M with \\
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \u{c_myenv_blank_line_tl} } % single ^^M
   { \c{\\} } % replace with \\
   \l_myenv_body_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\AtBeginEnvironment{myenv}{\obeylines}
\newcounter{stanzanumber}
\newcommand{\addstanzanumber}{~||~\stepcounter{stanzanumber}\thestanzanumber}
\newcommand{\says}[1]{\hspace{-2em}\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
Laborum molestias nam
possimus omnis. Libero sit
maiores quas asperiores nobis
est nulla. Culpa sequi iste deserunt.

Adipisci fuga et quis dicta est et
odit. Illo aut nulla qui incidunt
necessitatibus nulla qui. Sunt
cumque voluptatem quasi quam 

\says{the peacock says\dots}
commodi culpa quaerat sunt.
Debitis accusantium et porro et
libero nulla ut est. Asperiores sed
exercitationem aut. Ex sapiente 

\says{the elephant says\dots}
Debitis nobis fugiat doloremque
voluptates enim ratione. Unde

magni beatae magni. Unde
voluptatum qui odio corporis quia. 
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: could you try in a `{multicols}{2}` environment? I would like that the empty line height is exactly equal to \baselineskip.