# Locally disable \vspace{0pt} adding vertical space

Tags: spacing, sectioning, vertical-spacing

I'm trying to ad a bit of vertical space at the beginning of a page.
Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,footsepline, headsepline]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{0mm}%
\section*{Header}
\end{document}
```

After a bit of searching i found another [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7676/why-does-vspace0pt-add-vertical-space) about the same problem. The culprit there is the the `\topsep` that gets added. The solution was to disable interlineskip with either `\offinterlineskip` or `\nointerlineskip`.

The problem hereby is that macro is a global toggle and disables it globally.

Now my question is: Can i somehow only disable it locally for this one spacing?
I don't want to accidentally break something else in the process and want to have the most idiomatic way to do it just for that one vspace.

Edit: Title wording

Comment: no, `\offinterlineskip` is global `\nointerlinskip` just affects the next box

Comment: `\offinterlineskip` is *local* in plain TeX and it seems that it is defined equivalently in latex.ltx. It is used for example in tables: locally in given `\vbox` but affects all lines.

Comment: II am a little lost in how to use these commands exactly since just putting them before/after my `\vspace*` won't change anything.

Comment: @AcademicCoder no because the section command will itself be adding space. It's not at all clear what effect you want, perhaps `\vspace*{-\topskip}` ??

Comment: ah as @wipet said, both are local declarations (ie respect tex groups) I used global here in I think the sense you meant that (unlike `\nointerlineskip` )  `\offinterlineskip` affects all following boxes, and if used as you show at the top level of the document would affect the rest of the document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, that's what i meant with "global" as it affects everything that follows like a toggle. I am not a friend of that toggle-style since it can unintended behaviour in the rest of the document. I think working with `\vspace*{-\topskip + <fixed sep>}` is the way to go here in my case.

Comment: The problem wasn't solved really by that. Neither adding `\offinterlineskip`, `\nointerlineskip`, `\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}` (or any combination) with `\vspace*{0pt}` produced no vertical space above the section. Even with not setting `\topskip` to 0pt and haveing a `\vspace*{-\topskip}` didn't got rid of the space ... i am clueless