# Blank page inserted after table of contents when vspace used on preceding page

Tags: vspace, clearpage

The sample code at the bottom of this post results in the following page order:

1. title page
2. metadata page
3. table of contents
4. blank page (seems to be continued from the table of contents)
5. chapter

I'm really scratching my head about why the blank page (4) shows up. As best I can tell, it seems to be related to a `\vspace*{\fill}` command I placed on page (2). But this is confusing to me. Doesn't that come *before* the table of contents?

I want to keep the `\vspace*{\fill}` because (in the actual book I'm typesetting) I'm using it to vertically center the content on the metadata page.

What's going on?

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}

%%%%%%%%
% Headers and footers.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\title{Sample title}
\author{Sample author}
\date{Sample date}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title page.

\begin{titlepage}

Sample title page.

\end{titlepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Metadata page.

\thispagestyle{empty}

\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}

Sample metadata page.

\vspace*{\fill}

{
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\tableofcontents
}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Sample chapter title}

Sample chapter text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you have (or need) `\topskip0pt`? Remove that and things turn back to normal...

Comment: It's a workaround for this issue: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7290/11376

Comment: I.e. as far as I know you can't have true vertical centering without this. (If there's a better way to do that, I'm all ears.)

Comment: You can use [absolute positioning](https://pastebin.com/raw/XL06LHqg) with [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic). It depends on what your metadata page looks like.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like using `{}` around the metadata page also gets the job done.

Comment: There are many ways to perform vertical centering.  The easiest is `\parbox[c][\textheight][c]{...}`  `\topskip` isn't used since the height of the `\parbox` is larger.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be late to the party. Setting `\topskip` mid-document is the cause of the problem.

If you really want to “precisely center” the metadata, issue `\mbox{}` and a negative space by `\topskip`. But I don't think it's necessary or even good for the purpose.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}

%%%%%%%%
% Headers and footers.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\title{Sample title}
\author{Sample author}
\date{Sample date}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title page.

\begin{titlepage}

Sample title page.

\end{titlepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Metadata page.

\thispagestyle{empty}

\mbox{}

\vspace{-\topskip}
\vspace{\fill}


Sample metadata page.

\vspace*{\fill}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Sample chapter title}

Sample chapter text.

\end{document}
```

This will have four pages.

By the way, adding braces around `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}` doesn't localize the setting, because `\setcounter` has global scope. Setting `LE,RO` or `LO,RE` with `oneside` only produces annoying warnings, because with `oneside` the parity of page numbers is not examined when the header or footer is produced.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even late! What would you say is the "proper" way to vertically center the metadata?

Comment: @ElliottSlaughter Just forget about the `\topskip`. Nobody is going to notice a difference of a few points, if any.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `\mainmatter` command moves to the next odd page when you are using the `oneside` class option.

Try this modified version of your MWE, for which thank you.

```
% chapterprob.tex  SE 577746

\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
%\documentclass[12pt]{book}

%%%%%%%%
% Headers and footers.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\title{Sample title}
\author{Sample author}
\date{Sample date}

\begin{document}
%\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title page.

\begin{titlepage}

Sample title page.

\end{titlepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Metadata page.

\thispagestyle{empty}

\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}

Sample metadata page.

\vspace*{\fill}

{
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\tableofcontents
}

%\mainmatter
%\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Sample chapter title}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

Sample chapter text.

\end{document}
```

Note that instead of `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` I have used `\pagenumbering` to change the representation of the page numbers (which is one of the things that the `\...matter` macros do).

Comment: `\mainmatter` does contain a `\cleardoublepage`, so this is one way to work around it. Per the other comments though this seems to be a bad interaction with setting `\topskip` without using braces to properly scope it. (I still don't understand why, but it seems like the best explanation at this point.)