# How to get a lower footnote position on one page only?

Tags: positioning, footnotes

I have a page before index/table of contents where I need to specify something to the reader but want to insert the detail only in the footnote. The output is similar to the code that I posted here.

I would like to have the footnote at the very bottom only on this page. I would like to have the text central to the page and the footnote distant to it, if possibile.

I have tried a lot of different suggestions found on this website, like `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}`, but I didn't achieved what I wanted. Using `\vspace` doesn't work and `\renewcommand` affects every footnote.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \pagestyle{plain}
    
    %\setlength{\footskip}{1in}
    %\setlength{\footins}{1in}
    
    %\setlength{\footnotesep}{1in}
    
    \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
      \vspace{1in}
      \kern-3pt
      \hrule width 0.4\columnwidth
      \kern 2.6pt}
      
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    
    \begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble} %senza numero pagine
    %\blankpage
    \pagebreak
    %non più necessari con twoside=true
    
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
        %\textbf{ \Large È consigliata la visualizzazione a due pagine}
    \textbf{ \Large AAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAA AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA\footnote{ AAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            \begin{itemize}
                \item AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAA 
                \item AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAA AAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                \item AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA
                \item AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAA
            \end{itemize} 
        } 
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \end{document}
```

EDIT: added images to make understand the problem in a better way

as you can see from the images, there is a lot of space below of the text, I would like to reduce the light blue space near to zero and the bottom of the yellow rectangle to overlap with the bottom border light blue rectangle

[image: Code Result]
[image: Colored Result]

Comment: So what's wrong with the output of the sample code? It seems to achieve more or less what you asked for.

Comment: Potentially related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7286/how-to-make-an-exact-vertically-centered-object-in-a-page

Comment: @frabjous i would like to have the footnote even lower, it has to much space from the bottom border of the page.

Comment: If this is the only page you need to change, I might consider something as simple as `\enlargethispage{2cm}`, which will shift the bottom margin down. Adjust `2cm` to whatever you like, though you might need to adjust the text above as well if you don't want it to shift at all.

Comment: @frabjous that worked! thank you very much! if someone would make it to all the document there is a way to set enlarge to all page? or there is another way in this case?