# How to vertically center content in ConTeXt?

Tags: vertical-alignment, context, context-mkiv

I would like to vertically center my title page. I have tried code like this, but it does not work:

```
\vfill
\startalignment[center]
    Title
\stopalignment
\vfill
```

- I am using ConTeXt, so the solutions at [Vertically center text on a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/vertically-center-text-on-a-page) did not work, however, solutions in plain TeX will be fine too.
- The documentation on [\setupalign](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupalign) at the ConTeXt wiki suggests there might be the option `lohi`, but it seems only to center content vertically when placed inside a frame.

How can I vertically center content on a page?

Comment: Have you tried [makeup](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupmakeup) which is the standard method to write title pages in ConTeXt

Comment: You are missing a `\dontleavehmode` immediately before the first `\vfill`. It is required because the top of a page is a special situation in vmode.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Aditya already answered, the most common way is to use `\startstandardmakeup`, as in:

```
\starttext
\startstandardmakeup
\startalignment[center] % or \centerline{...}
    {\definedfont[Bold at 40pt] Title}
\stopalignment
\stopstandardmakeup
document text
\stoptext
```

Comment: Don't use explicit align macros. You can use: `\setupmakeup[align=middle]`.

Comment: @Aditya Could you explain why not to use explicit align macros? I am an absolute ConTeXt beginner.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt: Because it is bad style. I will prefer using `\starttitlepagemakeup Title \stoptitlepagemakeup` rather than what is described in the solution (where `titlepage` makeup is appropriately defined).

Comment: @SergeStroobandt: To give an analogy, it will be a bad style in LaTeX to use `\section{\itseries First section}`. It is better to move the formatting setup in the preamble and use semantic markup in the document body.

Comment: this only horizontally centers my text :c

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a hack, but in my code this always works: place a `\phantom{x}` before the `\vfill` to get the desired effect.

Comment: This is a brutal hack!  (1) You shouldn't do this, (2) if you decide to to this use at least `\leavevmode\vfill` instead of `\phantom{x}\vfill`.

Comment: @HenriMenke, I know it's quite an old answer (and comment), I'm wondering why one option is preferable to the other.