# How to move signature to the bottom of the page in ConTeXt's letter module?

Tags: context, letters

I'm using standalone ConTeXt 2017.03.26 16:15, and trying to do some fancy crazy stuff with letter module - as much as I can, 'cause seems a big part of available documentation about it is outdated.

However, I'm trying to place the 'closing' section (the closing line and signature) at the bottom of the page (not inside the footer, but above it - still on the 'text' area) - no success, though:

```
\usemodule[letter]

\setuplettersection[content][after={\vss}]
%\setuplettersection[signature][before={\vss}]
%\setuplettersection[content][after={\leavevmode\vfill}]
%\setuplettersection[closing][before={\leavevmode\vfill}]

\startletter
[opening={Dear Reader,},
closing={Best regards,},
signature={The TeXnician}]

\input knuth

\stopletter
```

- Trying with `\setuplettersection[content][after={\vss}]` or `\setuplettersection[closing][before={\vss}]`, throws a "Infinite glue shrinkage found on current page".
- The [`\vfill` hack](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54574/how-to-vertically-center-content-in-context#comment789632_225619) (`\setuplettersection[content][after={\leavevmode\vfill}]` or `\setuplettersection[closing][before={\leavevmode\vfill}]`) does exactly nothing visible on the output.
- With `\setupletterframe[closing][location={low,bottom}]` nothing happens, too.

The only thing that sort of works is setting `\setuplettersection[content][spaceafter={some \blank factor}]` (or, you know, `\setuplettersection[closing][spacebefore={some \blank factor}]`). Needless to say it's not an elegant solution at all, and you need to 'guess' a measure that fills between the content of each letter's content and the bottom of the page (minus height of 'closing').

Is there something I can do about this? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you add some code as MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `before` key of the letter section.  Unfortunately this is also not in the [manual](https://bitbucket.org/wolfs/correspondence/downloads/correspondence.pdf).  However, you can find it in the [commands overview](https://bitbucket.org/wolfs/correspondence/downloads/commands.pdf).

```
\usemodule[letter]

\setuplettersection[closing][before=\vfill]

\startletter
[opening={Dear Reader,},
closing={Best regards,},
signature={The TeXnician}]

\input knuth

\stopletter
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I figured out it was my fault for setting `\setupletteroptions[position=yes]` and nothing was working because of it. Not quite sure what does that, though.