# How to vertically center a piece of text on a page?

Tags: plain-tex

I've been searching how to center a piece of text vertically on a page, since I wanted to create a cover for my reports with the Title centered both vertically and horizontally. I first tried the following code:

```
\vfil
\centerline{Title}
\vfil

\eject\end
```

But this isn't centered vertically. So I found 
[this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225619/172315), and so I added `\leavevmode` to the beginning of the file. And it worked! I also tried putting instead `\indent`at the beginning of the original. And it also worked!

So my question is: **Why do you need to start a paragraph or "leave vertical mode" before the first `\vfil` in order for the glue to work in centering the text veertically on the page?** It all seems very odd, indeed.

Comment: Because glue is discardable at a page break.  p112 of *The TeXBook* explains the mechanism.

Comment: You can also use `\null` or `\hbox{}` or... many other options. The reason/idea of discarding glue at the top of a page is similar to discarding glue at the start of a line: after a line/page break, you don't want “leftover” glue from the previous line/page to affect the current one.

Comment: @JohnKormylo -- This question is about plain tex.  `\vspace` is latex only.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments `\TeX` ignores glue at the end or top of a
page as it does ignore glue at the end or start of a line.

But `plain \TeX` knows some commands for glue that does not vanish; you do not need to enter a special command like `\leavevmode`.  For glue
at the top of a page `\topglue` is used instead of `\topskip`. (And there is `\hglue` and `\vglue` as non-discarding variants of `\hskip` and `\vskip`.)

For your problem this `\topglue` provides a solution. As `\bye` contains `\vfill`, i.e., glue with specification 0pt plus 1fill, input

```
\topglue 0pt plus 1fill
\centerline{Titel}
\bye
```

Comment: It couldn't be easier, many thanks.