# center horizontally and vertically a block of text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I would center horizontally and vertically a block of text as if it was an abstract text block.How can I do?

I tried this:

```
\null\vfill
\begin{center}

\end{center}
\vfill\null
```

it It correct?

Comment: The second `\null` should be `\clearpage`; I'd use `\vspace*{\fill}` instead of `\null\vfill`, but it's personal preference.

Comment: But how can I justify text...?

Comment: Use a `minipage` inside `center`.

Comment: How does minipage work?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A "correct" way could be

```
\clearpage
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
Text that will be justified
...
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\vfill % equivalent to \vspace{\fill}
\clearpage
```

The top vertical space should be `\vspace*`, so it doesn't disappear at the break. The justified text will be on a line width that's 6/10 of the normal line width, change the fraction to suit you.

You can in a similar way decide also for different spaces at the top and at the bottom; for instance

```
\clearpage
\vspace*{\stretch{2}}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
Text that will be justified
...
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\vspace{\stretch{3}}
\clearpage
```

will leave spaces in the proportion 2/3; something of this kind can turn useful for a dedication page, as the dedication is usually not in the center of the page.

If you need that the text inside the minipage has indented paragraphs as the normal text, then `center` and `minipage` are not good. This can be accomplished by a more complicated construction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{list}{}{%
  \leftmargin=.2\textwidth
  \rightmargin=.2\textwidth
  \listparindent=\parindent
  \itemindent=\parindent
  \itemsep=0pt
  \parsep=0pt}
\item\relax
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{list}
\vfill % equivalent to \vspace{\fill}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

The package `lipsum` just produces some text.

Comment: The `\vspace*{\fill}` just added an additional page for me. Any explanation as why that's happening? Any why do you use it would be helpful.

Comment: @user14492 A bit too generic, isn't it?