# Text indentation for dedication page

Tags: paragraphs

I am using stock book template and would like to create a dedication page. I have used [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70718/74736) answer to align the text vertically and my current code is the following:

```
\cleardoublepage
\vspace*{\stretch{3}}
\textbf{DEDICATION}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam bibendum nisl et elementum placerat. Vivamus placerat, erat sed pretium malesuada, est lacus ultricies nibh, id rutrum quam lacus et enim. Nunc imperdiet pretium sagittis. Quisque mattis pharetra enim at scelerisque. Quisque id ornare orci. In sit amet leo non leo commodo viverra in ut ipsum.

Aliquam scelerisque, urna nec elementum pharetra, ipsum tellus luctus elit, non malesuada sem nunc vitae tortor. Cras lorem magna, faucibus a magna id, tincidunt euismod turpis. Vestibulum viverra suscipit nibh, at sollicitudin orci. Aliquam mollis nisi lacinia suscipit volutpat. Nunc velit sem, sagittis vitae lacus.
\vspace{\stretch{1}}
\clearpage
```

The code produces this page

[image]

Now, what I would like to do is to add some **left padding** to the text (say 3 or 4 cm). I have made an extensive search and have found no easy way to do it. Is this really that complicated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy to do with `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` from the `geometry` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\cleardoublepage
\newgeometry{left=6cm,right=3.8cm}
\vspace*{\stretch{3}}
\textbf{DEDICATION}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam bibendum nisl et elementum placerat. Vivamus placerat, erat sed pretium malesuada, est lacus ultricies nibh, id rutrum quam lacus et enim. Nunc imperdiet pretium sagittis. Quisque mattis pharetra enim at scelerisque. Quisque id ornare orci. In sit amet leo non leo commodo viverra in ut ipsum.

Aliquam scelerisque, urna nec elementum pharetra, ipsum tellus luctus elit, non malesuada sem nunc vitae tortor. Cras lorem magna, faucibus a magna id, tincidunt euismod turpis. Vestibulum viverra suscipit nibh, at sollicitudin orci. Aliquam mollis nisi lacinia suscipit volutpat. Nunc velit sem, sagittis vitae lacus.
\vspace{\stretch{1}}
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Another method:* modify, then restore the value of `\leftskip`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\cleardoublepage
\leftskip=4cm
\newgeometry{left=6cm}
\vspace*{\stretch{3}}
\textbf{DEDICATION}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam bibendum nisl et elementum placerat. Vivamus placerat, erat sed pretium malesuada, est lacus ultricies nibh, id rutrum quam lacus et enim. Nunc imperdiet pretium sagittis. Quisque mattis pharetra enim at scelerisque. Quisque id ornare orci. In sit amet leo non leo commodo viverra in ut ipsum.

Aliquam scelerisque, urna nec elementum pharetra, ipsum tellus luctus elit, non malesuada sem nunc vitae tortor. Cras lorem magna, faucibus a magna id, tincidunt euismod turpis. Vestibulum viverra suscipit nibh, at sollicitudin orci. Aliquam mollis nisi lacinia suscipit volutpat. Nunc velit sem, sagittis vitae lacus.
\vspace{\stretch{1}}
\clearpage
\leftskip=0cm
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a double sided document and your solution seems to confuse the page margins - they are the same as other left-side pages, but should be as right-side pages.

Comment: The `book` class, that I use, is two--sided by default, and I have no problem. Wich class of document do you use? Geometry might interfere with it.

Comment: I am using the standard class: `\documentclass[a4paper]{book}`. The dedication page appears on the right-hand side, but the margins are as the left-hand side.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you mean the outer margin on the dedication page is the same as the inner margin on other pages? I added another solution without geometry, based on the value of `\leftskip`.

Comment: Thanks, the solution with `\leftskip` worked. Regarding the margins: the dedication page is on the right side. It's outer (right) margin is the same as the inner (right) margin on other left-side pages. So it does not look like a right side page, although it is displayed on the right-hand side.

Comment: Yes, I should have specified a value for the right margin in the `geometry` solution. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 4):

You can fudge this using `list` environment (this is how `quote` etc work):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{dedication}{\cleardoublepage\vspace*{\stretch{3}}%
     \list{}{}\item\relax\textbf{Dedication}\newline}%
    {\endlist\vspace*{\stretch{1}}\clearpage}

\begin{document}
  \begin{dedication}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{dedication}
\end{document}
```

Just for fun I've wrapped this into a "dedication" environment. Here's an image:

[image]