# Flush poems to bottom of page

Tags: verse

MWE

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{%
\nopagebreak{\raggedleft\footnotesize\textit{#1}\par}}

\poemtitle{Fleas}
%\settowidth{\versewidth}{You can’t tell a he from a she.}
\begin{verse}%[\versewidth]
What a funny thing is a flea. \\
You can’t tell a he from a she. \\
But he can. And she can. \\
Whoopee! \\
\end{verse}
\attrib{2015}

\newpage

\poemtitle{Fleas}
%\settowidth{\versewidth}{You can’t tell a he from a she.}
\begin{altverse}%[\versewidth]
What a funny thing is a flea. \\
You can’t tell a he from a she. \\
But he can. And she can. \\
Whoopee! \\
\end{altverse}

\begin{altverse}%[\versewidth]
What a funny thing is a flea. \\
You can’t tell a he from a she. \\
But he can. And she can. \\
Whoopee! \\
\end{altverse}

\attrib{2015}

\end{document}
```

But, That I want,

[image]

All the poems at the bottom of the pages. And poems are flushleft. The date, flushright.

How is it changing macro in my MWE?

I have only one problem. Here the picture. White space in poems.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you want the poem at the bottom of the page?  Or do you want it centered on the page?

Comment: Flushing content to the bottom of the page is achieved using something like `\mbox{}\par\vfill \poemtitle...`. However, your question isn't quite clear in that regard.

Comment: And for centering, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70718

Comment: @Thérèse, yes, poem at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Werner, I am editing.

Comment: Then put `\null\vfill` before the poem.

Comment: @Thérèse `\vspace*{\fill}` is the preferred LaTeX way.

Comment: Try `\raggedright` rather than `\raggedleft` for right-aligned dates?

Comment: @Thérèse, edit the my question.

Comment: Try `\setlength{\leftmargini}{0em}` to remove the unwanted space at the beginning of the lines.

Comment: `texdoc verse` page 7 to do what @Thérèse suggests in a way which does not affect all list environments (which includes a lot of things you probably don't realise are lists).

Comment: What about the titles? Should they still be centred horizontally?