# Proper Horizontal and Vertical Centering (for Sections)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning

I have the following problem:
[image]
I attempted to center it both vertically and horizontally, however the second line, as you can see, is not centered. For clarity, here is how I'd expect it to look (taken from Word):
[image]
I am aware that it is a different font, but that doesn't matter.

Any help to make the first Section Heading look like the second would be greatly appreciated!

To center it, I used the code from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70714/center-horizontally-and-vertically-a-block-of-text) answer

Here is the code (it is probably terrible, I just started using Latex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\titleformat{\section}{\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont\fontsize{72pt}{86.4pt}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\section*{Example Section}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\vfill
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: a section heading formatting needs to be part of the heading definition, if you mean by your link you put `\section` inside `begin{center}` that's wrong, but as you have shown no code it is hard to guess

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, you are completely right! Sorry for forgetting about it

Comment: your example can still not be used to make the image you show, we do not know the text width (which seems to be very narrow based on your image) or the definition of `\section`,

Comment: do you have no text in the section? centering the heading is very common but vertically centering it is rather odd (and consequently not as directly supported by standard definitions for section headings)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the text would be on the next page, I know it is an odd design choice, but I kinda like it

Comment: the example makes `! Paragraph ended before \ttl@format@ii was complete.` here? do you get the same (after an error, it's  best to post the error message, not the pdf output, which is just arbitrary after an error recovery)

Comment: There is a `}` missing after `72pt`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Terribly sorry again, somehow managed to lose the } there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

All the formatting should be in the definition of `\section` not in the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand\zzz[1]{%
\clearpage
\vspace*{\fill}
{\centering\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont\fontsize{72pt}{86.4pt}\bfseries#1\par}
\vspace*{\fill}
\clearpage}

\titleformat{\section}{\zzz}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section*{Example Section}

zzz
\end{document}
```