# Vertically align table in a page

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

I would try to align vertically a table in a page. I have a page contains only a table and I would put it at the center of the page. To center it horizontally I used \centering but what command should I use to center it vertically?

Comment: Not sure but this might help: 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/vertically-center-text-on-a-page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a page containing only a table, there's no need to put excessive code. It's enough to define a table, as it is. The table will be put in the middle of page, automatically.

```
\begin{table}
\caption{...}
\label{...}
...
\end{table}
```

Comment: you might want to specify that it's on a page by itself -- `\begin{table}[p]`