# TeX ignores \vskip at the beginning of document

Tags: spacing, tex-core

Here is a simple Plain TeX snippet for demonstration

```
\vskip 3in
Aaaaa
\vskip 3in
Bbbbb
\end
```

When I compile this with pdftex, I expect to see a 3-inch-high blank space, then Aaaaa, followed by another 3-inch-high blank space, then Bbbbb. But the first \vskip appears to be ignored by TeX.

On the other hand, when I do this

```
\hrule height 0pt
\vskip 3in
Aaaaa
\vskip 3in
Bbbbb
\end
```

The output is what I expect. But I see no reason why a dummy 0-point-hrule is necessary.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Vertical space is removed at page breaks. The start of a document is considered to happen at a page break. Use `\vglue` instead of `\vskip` for "non disappearing space".

From the TeXbook, p. 352

> You can get horizontal space that never disappears by saying `\hglue<glue>`; this space is able to stretch or shrink. Similarly, there's a vertical analog, `\vglue<glue>`.

There is a difference in how pages and paragraphs are treated: `\hskip` at the start of a paragraph doesn't disappear, because of the indent box that's always inserted at the start of a paragraph.

If you notice, the first example in the TeXbook, `story.tex`, starts with a `\hrule` just to avoid the following vertical space to disappear.

---

The above considerations are for Plain TeX; in LaTeX one should use `\vspace` for "disappearing space" and `\vspace*` for the non disappearing variety.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for the informative answer.