# Evenly spacing figures vertically across page

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am compiling an appendix for my dissertation consisting only of figures. Currently the gap between the top figure and the top of the page is smaller than the gap between the lower figure and the bottom of the page. I want to place three figures on each page, with even vertical spacing.  How would I adapt the following code to do this:

```
\begin{figure}
\centerline{
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/DCP/pen1-1}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/DCP/cbr1-1} 
\end{minipage}
}
\caption[]{DCP test 1.1}
\label{graphs1-1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centerline{
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/DCP/pen1-2}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/DCP/cbr1-2}
\end{minipage}
}
\caption[]{DCP test 1.2}
\label{graphs1-2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centerline{
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/DCP/pen1-3}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/DCP/cbr1-3}
\end{minipage}
}
\caption[]{DCP test 1.3}
\label{graphs1-3}
\end{figure}
```

Note: each figure consists of two graphs side-by-side.

Comment: You could put them into a tabular.  To fix the vertical spacing you might add a \rule{0pt}{\somefixeddistance} to each row.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want the `figure` environment. Try

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{appfigure}
  {\par\vspace{\fill}\centering
   \begin{adjustwidth}{-.12\textwidth}{-.12\textwidth}%
   \def\@captype{figure}%
   \setkeys{Gin}{width=.6\textwidth}}
  {\end{adjustwidth}\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix with figures}

\begin{appfigure}
\includegraphics{figs/DCP/pen1-1}\hfill
\includegraphics[]{figs/DCP/cbr1-1} 
\caption[]{DCP test 1.1}
\label{graphs1-1}
\end{appfigure}

\begin{appfigure}
\includegraphics{figs/DCP/pen1-1}\hfill
\includegraphics[]{figs/DCP/cbr1-1} 
\caption[]{DCP test 1.1}
\label{graphs1-2}
\end{appfigure}

\begin{appfigure}
\includegraphics{figs/DCP/pen1-1}\hfill
\includegraphics[]{figs/DCP/cbr1-1} 
\caption[]{DCP test 1.1}
\label{graphs1-3}
\end{appfigure}

\begin{appfigure}
\includegraphics{figs/DCP/pen1-1}\hfill
\includegraphics[]{figs/DCP/cbr1-1} 
\caption[]{DCP test 1.1}
\label{graphs1-4}
\end{appfigure}

\begin{appfigure}
\includegraphics{figs/DCP/pen1-1}\hfill
\includegraphics[]{figs/DCP/cbr1-1} 
\caption[]{DCP test 1.1}
\label{graphs1-5}
\end{appfigure}

\pagebreak

\begin{appfigure}
\includegraphics{figs/DCP/pen1-1}\hfill
\includegraphics[]{figs/DCP/cbr1-1} 
\caption[]{DCP test 1.1}
\label{graphs1-6}
\end{appfigure}

\begin{appfigure}
\includegraphics{figs/DCP/pen1-1}\hfill
\includegraphics[]{figs/DCP/cbr1-1} 
\caption[]{DCP test 1.1}
\label{graphs1-7}
\end{appfigure}

\begin{appfigure}
\includegraphics{figs/DCP/pen1-1}\hfill
\includegraphics[]{figs/DCP/cbr1-1} 
\caption[]{DCP test 1.1}
\label{graphs1-8}
\end{appfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{vplace}[1]

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \includegraphics[width=28.8mm]{img1v1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \includegraphics[width=28.8mm]{img1v1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \includegraphics[width=28.8mm]{img1v1}
\end{figure}
\end{vplace}

\end{document}
```

or look here [Vertically center text on a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/vertically-center-text-on-a-page.)

Comment: If I input this code into the appendix, I get the error

    ! LaTeX Error: Command \@texttop already defined.

Comment: What class you are using report or book?

Comment: I'm using a class based on memoir

Comment: @boondock Try new code with memoir class.