# How can I center my whole document while using the Memoir class?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir

The Memoir class by default does the left/right page difference in centering. How can I use the memoir class while making the *whole thing* centered? All I've found was this thread

[Vertically center text on a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/vertically-center-text-on-a-page)

but those solutions seem to just be for making a single page centered.

Comment: Do you want equal margins all around, then? As in, 1" on the top, bottom, left, and right, regardless of whether it's a verso or recto page?

Comment: @MikeRenfro I'm fine with how the top and bottom margins are but yeah I'd like the left and right to both be 1" or 1.5"

Comment: I think all you're looking for is `\setlrmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}` and `\checkandfixthelayout` from sections 2.4.2 and 2.7 of the [memoir manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf), then. 2.7 has an exhaustive list of things you may want to set, but you might not need all of them.

Comment: If you are not using a two-page spread, you may find it easiest to use `\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}`. This should centre the textblock with respect to the physical page.