# Vertically center (contents of) environment on page

Tags: positioning

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  landscape
]{article}

\usepackage[
  a6paper,
  margin = 0cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newenvironment{horse}
{
 \topskip0pt
 \vspace*{\fill}
 \begin{center}
 \fontsize{50}{56}\selectfont
 }
{
 \end{center}
 \vspace*{\fill}
 %
}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\begin{horse}
  Alle lande\\[0.5ex] og\\[0.5ex] deres hovedst{\ae}der
\end{horse}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I would like the contents of the `horse` environment to be placed vertically centered on the page. As can be seen if the code is compiled, this doesn't happen; how do I fix this?

P.S. I just "stole" the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2327/15874 and modified it a bit.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek When I compile the code, the text is well below the center of the page. `:-(` (See added screenshot.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little simplified example (`\centering` instead of environment `center` and line ends commented):

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  landscape
]{article}

\usepackage[
  a6paper,
  margin = 0cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newenvironment{horse}{%
  \setlength{\topskip}{0pt}%
  \centering
  \vspace*{\fill}%
  % \nointerlineskip
  \fontsize{50}{56}\selectfont
  % \sbox0{Alle lande}%
  % \showthe\ht0
}{%
  \par
  \vspace{\fill}%
  % \setlength{\showboxdepth}{\maxdimen}%
  % \setlength{\showboxbreadth}{\maxdimen}%
  % \tracingonline=1 %
  % \showlists
}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\begin{horse}
  Alle lande\\[0.5ex] og\\[0.5ex] deres hovedst{\ae}der
\end{horse}

\end{document}
```

Enabling the four lines with `\showlists` reveals:

```
### current page:
\write-{}
\glue(\topskip) 0.0
\rule(0.0+0.0)x*
\penalty 10000
\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill
\glue 0.0
\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
\glue(\baselineskip) 21.83911
\hbox(34.16089+0.0)x421.10078, glue set 109.61919fil
.\glue(\leftskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.\OT1/lmr/m/n/50 A
.\OT1/lmr/m/n/50 l
.\OT1/lmr/m/n/50 l
.\OT1/lmr/m/n/50 e
```

All is fine except for the large contribution of the `\baselineskip`. The height of the first line is 34.16089pt, but the line spacing is 56pt. The difference is added on top of the first row:

```
\glue(\baselineskip) 21.83911
```

This can be turned off by `\nointerlineskip`. After enabling it in the code above, the result is:

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

try

```
\newcommand\HUGE{\fontsize{50}{56}\selectfont}

\newenvironment{horse}
  {\vspace*{\fill}
   \centering\HUGE}
  {\vfill~\newpage}
```

[image]

Comment: That is above the center of the page.

Comment: use for example a character "g" in the last line and you'll see that the baselines are right.

Comment: I see your point, but then how do I vertically centered the actual text on the page, and not the text if I use a character with the lowest point as low as possible on the line?