# How to fix the "missing $ inserted" when you are not in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, overleaf, posters, missing

I just started to learn how to work in Overleaf, so I'm still such a noob. Anyways, I'm doing a project for my class and I don't know how to fix the "missing $ inserted issue". The converted code does look how i want it to look, but the error bothers me. I will be really grateful if somebody can help me. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[20pt,,margin=1in,innermargin=-4.5in,blockverticalspace=-0.25in]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=42in,paperheight=32.5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{multicol}


\title{Exercise}
\date{October 2022}

\begin{document}

\begin{columns}
%COLUMN 1
\column{0.30}
%Block A
\block{\Huge Why participate in one?}{

\vcenter{{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{icon1.png}}}}
\huge \textsl{ Meet new people}

\vcenter{{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{icon2.png}}}}
\huge \textsl{ Build your resume}}

\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

[image: my code]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  If you highlight your code while editing and click `{}`, it will become properly formatted (we've done this for you).  You're right to be bothered by the error: it means that you lucked into getting the output you wanted.  I'm not finding a `{columns}` environment nor a `\column` command in the multicols package.  What are you aiming to do with that?

Comment: Where did you find `\vcenter`? It can only be used in math mode. Remove it. But using `\hbox` is not LaTeX.

Comment: Your document source is over-complicated. Moreover, your bad luck is that you are using LaTeX which sets `\errorcontextlines` to zero. So, you don't see the crucial part of the error message: `<to be read again>  \vcenter`. If you see this then you can resume that `\vcenter` is the problem outside the math mode and TeX starts math mode inserting `$`. Of course, `\vcenter` can be used only in math mode, because this primitive has to know the placement of math axis: the vertical centering is done around math axis.

Comment: Sounds like you want [vertical alignment - Vertically center text on a page - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/vertically-center-text-on-a-page). Basically just don't "randomly guess" LaTeX commands and you should be mostly safe.