# Please help to rectify the cover pages for thesis related documents

Tags: formatting, sectioning, koma-script, front-matter, covers

I need to attach the supporting documents related to the thesis, each category under a separate title cover page. I have tried to make a basic format, however, it is not looking good. My code is dirty, but may give an idea of the situation. There is no pre-specified format. Although I have commented the PDF attachments, but they will be present in the actual document ( That did not create any problem as such). The only restriction is that the design should not affect other pages in the thesis.

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,a4paper,11pt,oneside,chapterprefix=true,sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[margin=1in,head=27.2pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\addchap{All supporting documents}
\addsec{PhD supporting documents}
\vspace{25mm}
\hrulefill
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{center}
 \textbf{Enrollment Certificate\\ \vspace{5mm} Coursework Certificate\\ \vspace{5mm}Registration Certificate\\}
 \end{center}
\hrulefill

\vspace{5mm}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Certificates/Enrollment.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Certificates/Coursework_completion.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Certificates/Registration.pdf}
\clearpage
\addsec{\Large \bfseries Publication supporting documents}
\vspace{55mm}
\hrulefill
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{center}
{ \huge \bfseries Journals  ~\\[0.3cm] }
\end{center}
\vspace{5mm}
\hrulefill
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Journals/EVOS_Published.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Journals/wpc.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Journals/sensors.pdf}
\newpage
\vspace{55mm}
\hrulefill
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{center}
{ \huge \bfseries Conferences  ~\\[0.3cm] }
\end{center}
\vspace{5mm}
\hrulefill
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Conferences/Haldia_cert.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Conferences/Haldia.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Conferences/Thermo_cert.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Conferences/Thermometer.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Conferences/Brainware_cert.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Conferences/Brainware.pdf}
\newpage
\vspace{15mm}
\hrulefill
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{center}
{ \huge \bfseries Book Chapters  ~\\[0.3cm] }
\end{center}
\hrulefill
\vspace{5mm}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Books/Book1.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Books/Book2.pdf}
\newpage
\vspace{15mm}
\hrulefill
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{center}
{ \huge \bfseries International Patents and recognition ~\\[0.3cm] }
\end{center}
\hrulefill
\vspace{5mm}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Patents/Patent Certificate1.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Patents/Patent Certificate2.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Patents/SA Patent Certificate.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Patents/TOI.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: "Looking good" is often in the eyes of the beholder. Is it possible for you to give some indication of what doesn't look good?

Comment: If you reproduce the MWE, you can visibly see few disparities such as the top and bottom \hrulefill are of different length for Publication documents. The one line "Journal" or conference should be at the middle of the page with bigger font (22-24pt), are to be name a few.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot?

Comment: Modified OP and added a screenshot

Comment: You have e.g. `\addsec`, a different size of font and different vertical spacing for 'Publication supporting documents', so of course it will look different? Are you sure you want to use `geometry` with this class? See the documentation for reasons you maybe shouldn't.

Comment: Yes geometry modification was required to adjust the margin for some big tables and the default geometry was not producing the intended results for a few pages containing figures and tables.

Comment: The different lengths is because you started a new paragraph and there is a paragraph indent. Try `\noindent\hrulefill` instead. For vertical centering, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336688/119) gives a simple method, but there are also other ways (see other answers to that question).

Comment: Thanks Willie, that solved the indentation problem and I solved the spacing problem through experiment and google. I have posted the final code as answer, in case anyone needs it in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer courtesy @Willie

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,a4paper,11pt,oneside,chapterprefix=true,sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}

% Set your geometry options if necessary
\geometry{margin=1in}

\begin{document}

\addchap{All supporting documents}
\addsec{PhD supporting documents}

\vspace{35mm}
\noindent\hrulefill
\begin{center}
\Large \textbf{Enrollment Certificate\\ \vspace{5mm} Coursework Certificate\\ \vspace{5mm} Registration Certificate\\}
\end{center}
\noindent\hrulefill
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Certificates/Enrollment.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Certificates/Coursework_completion.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Certificates/Registration.pdf}
\newpage
\addsec{Publication supporting documents}
\vspace{10cm}
\noindent\hrulefill
\begin{center}
    
    \Huge\textbf{Journal}
    \par\vspace{5mm}\par
    \hrulefill
\end{center}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Journals/EVOS_Published.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Journals/wpc.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Journals/sensors.pdf}
\newpage
\vspace*{10cm}
\noindent\hrulefill
\begin{center}
   
    \Huge\textbf{Conference}
    \par\vspace{5mm}\par
    \hrulefill
\end{center}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Conferences/Haldia.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Conferences/Thermo_cert.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Conferences/Thermometer.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Conferences/Brainware_cert.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Conferences/Brainware.pdf}

\newpage
\vspace*{10cm}
\noindent\hrulefill
\begin{center}
    \Huge\textbf{Book Chapter}
    \par\vspace{5mm}\par
    \hrulefill
\end{center}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Books/Book1.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Books/Book2.pdf}
\newpage
\vspace*{10cm}
\noindent\hrulefill
\begin{center}
    \Huge\textbf{International Patent}
    \par\vspace{5mm}\par
    \hrulefill
\end{center}

%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Patents/Patent Certificate1.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Patents/Patent Certificate2.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Patents/SA Patent Certificate.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Patents/TOI.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `\noindent`, you can also move all `\hrulefill` into the `center` environment, because `center` does not use an indent of the first line of a paragraph:

```latex
\documentclass[listof=totoc,a4paper,11pt,oneside,chapterprefix=true,sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}

% Set your geometry options if necessary
\geometry{margin=1in}

\begin{document}

\addchap{All supporting documents}
\addsec{PhD supporting documents}

\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
  \hrulefill\\[1ex]
  \Large \textbf{Enrollment Certificate\\ \vspace{5mm} Coursework Certificate\\ \vspace{5mm} Registration Certificate\\}
  \hrulefill
\end{center}
\vfill
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Certificates/Enrollment.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Certificates/Coursework_completion.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Certificates/Registration.pdf}
\newpage
\addsec{Publication supporting documents}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
  \hrulefill\\[1ex]
  \Huge\textbf{Journal}
  \par
  \hrulefill
\end{center}
\vfill
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Journals/EVOS_Published.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Journals/wpc.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Journals/sensors.pdf}
\newpage
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
  \hrulefill\\[1ex]
  \Huge\textbf{Conference}
  \par
  \hrulefill
\end{center}
\vfill
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Conferences/Haldia.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Conferences/Thermo_cert.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Conferences/Thermometer.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Conferences/Brainware_cert.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Conferences/Brainware.pdf}
\newpage
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
  \hrulefill\\[1ex]
  \Huge\textbf{Book Chapter}
  \par
  \hrulefill
\end{center}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Books/Book1.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Books/Book2.pdf}
\vfill
\newpage
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
  \hrulefill\\[1ex]
  \Huge\textbf{International Patent}
  \par
  \hrulefill
\end{center}
\vfill
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Patents/Patent Certificate1.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Patents/Patent Certificate2.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Patents/SA Patent Certificate.pdf}
%\includepdf[pages={1}]{./Patents/TOI.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]